# typesetting different characters with different colors in a DNA sequence

Tags: formatting, color, verbatim

I have created a macro which I used to format DNA sequences, as they should be in the monospaced font and uppercased:

```
\newcommand{\DNA}[1]{\texttt{\uppercase{#1}}}
```

Now I have a column with some different DNA sequences on different rows, lets say:

```
1 & \DNA{GCATCCAATGCC}\\
2 & \DNA{GGGACCAATGCG}\\
3 & \DNA{TTATCCAATCTC}\
```

I would like to color each character (base) in the DNA sequence with a different color, as it easier for the reader to see certain patterns (in this case the reoccuring CCAAT sequence, a putative Hap complex binding domain). 
(for example as done [here](http://umanitoba.ca/afs/plant_science/courses/PLNT7690/lec07/lec07.3.html))

that means, all
A -> Red
T -> Green
C -> Blue
G -> Black

Is there a way to do this, or a verbatim package in which this can be achieved ?
Thanks alot for your help!

### ----------

Liu's example posted works well, but not in my tabular/floatrow table
Tobi's example works well in all environments tested..

Thanks again for your great help all!

Comment: omg guys... I just went to the groceries, and after returning I see three splendid answers to my question... I feel very humble now.

Comment: Is there also a way to put a line under a specified nucleotide?

Comment: @Ros: You could change a literate line like `{B}{\textcolor{blue}{B}}{1}` to `{B}{\underline{B}}{1}` in my above example.

Comment: Thanks, toby! But I don't want to underline all B's. E.g. if I want to emphasize a start-codon in, let's say, the sequence ACTACATGCA, I only want to underline ATG, and not the other nucleotides.

Comment: You might want to have a look at the [`texshade`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/texshade) package (Typesetting nucleotide and peptide alignments) and maybe also [`textopo`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/textopo) (for shaded membrane protein topology plots) by the same author.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Like this?

[EDIT: I changed the example so it doesn’t touch other listings.]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,xcolor}
\lstdefinestyle{dna}{%
    literate={A}{\textcolor{green}{A}}{1}
        {B}{\textcolor{blue}{B}}{1}
        {C}{\textcolor{red}{C}}{1}
        {a}{\textcolor{green}{A}}{1}
        {b}{\textcolor{blue}{B}}{1}
        {c}{\textcolor{red}{C}}{1},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
}
\newcommand{\DNA}[1]{%
    \lstinline[style=dna]{#1}%
}
\begin{document}
\lstinline{ABCabc}\quad\DNA{bbCa}
\section{Somthing about \DNA{abcabcababc}}
\end{document}
```

You can use it also in commands like `\section`
See the `listings`manual for more info.

Comment: +1 for `listings`. Thanks to the more robust implementation, it works better in macro arguments.

Answer (score 12):

(Revised version following Martin's suggestion)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begingroup
\catcode`A\active
\catcode`T\active
\catcode`C\active
\catcode`G\active
\gdef A{\textcolor{red}{\string A}}
\gdef T{\textcolor{green}{\string T}}
\gdef C{\textcolor{blue}{\string C}}
\gdef G{\textcolor{black}{\string G}}
\endgroup

\DeclareRobustCommand\DNA[1]{\begingroup
  \scantokens{%
    \catcode`A\active
    \catcode`C\active
    \catcode`G\active
    \catcode`T\active
    \ttfamily#1\endinput}%
  \endgroup}

\begin{document}

\section{\DNA{ACGT}}

\DNA{ACGTACGT}, \fbox{\DNA{ACGTACGT}}

\end{document}
```

---

A more professional choice is to use [`texshade` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/texshade), especially for biology. I almost forgot it. It is quite complex for me, and there're some predefined styles. You'd better read the manual first.

Comment: I just looked at some examples in the manual of texshade, and indeed it's a very nice package. However, in this case I have already preprocessed information. In which I already truncated part of the sequence I want to show with a perlscript. I'm combining that information with some other tabular info

Comment: Your example doesn't work in the xelatex / fontspec environment. I will need to take a look into that.

Comment: @Timtico: The code I listed works fine with `fontspec` on my computer. Maybe you can provide more information about it. (egreg's code is actually the same.) BTW, I knew `texshade` from *LaTeX Graphics Companion*, but I've never used it in practice.

Comment: Yep, I didn't want to make it too complex. You can easily add some code for lowercase.

Comment: The solution doesnt work inside my floatrow environment (in which i make a tabular*, i will post an example)

Comment: In fact, I'd suggest Tobi's solution, it is more robust. You should not use my (and egreg's) `\DNA` in another command's argument, while Tobi's solution would works better. Or you can use `cprotect` package to solve the problem in my and egreg's solutions.

Comment: Instead of ``\symbol{`A}`` you could also use `\string A`. If you use `\scantokens` the `\DNA` macro could also be used in macro arguments.

Answer (score 6):

```
\begingroup\lccode`~=`A
\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\textcolor{red}{A}}
\begingroup\lccode`~=`T
\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\textcolor{green}{T}}

\begingroup\lccode`~=`C
\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\textcolor{blue}{C}}

\begingroup\lccode`~=`G
\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\textcolor{black}{G}}

\let\NX\noexpand
\def\DNAmathcodes{%
  \catcode`A=\active \catcode`T=\active
  \catcode`C=\active \catcode`G=\active
  \catcode`a=\active \catcode`t=\active
  \catcode`c=\active \catcode`g=\active
}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\DNA}{\bgroup\DNAmathcodes\doDNA}
\newcommand\doDNA[1]{\texttt{\uppercase{\scantokens{#1\NX}}}\egroup}


\begin{tabular}{ll}
1 & \DNA{GCATCCAATGCC}\\
2 & \DNA{GGGACCAATGCG}\\
3 & \DNA{TTATCCAATCTC}
\end{tabular}
```

Note: without `\noexpand`, `\scantokens` would add a space; but `\noexpand` contains an "a"! Also `\DNA` must be robustified, if we need it in a section title.

Comment: You could use `\scantokens` to allow `\DNA` to work in macro arguments. If you use `\lowercase` to define the letter macros you don't need to use ``\char`\A``, simply `A` etc. should do it.

Comment: The `\char`\A` remained from a try with `\mathcode`. Edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

For completeness, here is a solution using LuaTeX. I use LPEG to parse the input and then apply the appropriate style to it. The solution is in ConTeXt, but it should be easy to translate it to LaTeX.

```
\unexpanded\def\DNA#1%
    {\ctxcommand{dnaparse("#1")}}

\startluacode
  thirddata = thirddata or {}
  thirddata.dna = thirddata.dna or {}
  local dna = thirddata.dna

  dna.attributes ={ 
      A = { color = "red",   style = "mono" },
      T = { color = "green", style = "mono" },
      C = { color = "blue",  style = "mono" },
      G = { color = "black", style = "mono" },
      default = { color = "black", style = "mono"},
    }

  local function format(char)
    local hash = dna.attributes[char] or dna.attributes[default]
    context.style(hash, char)
  end

  local char = lpeg.S("ATCG") / format
  dna.parser = lpeg.Cs(char^0)


  function commands.dnaparse(str)
    dna.parser:match(str)
  end
\stopluacode

\starttext

  \DNA{GCATCCAATGCC}
  \DNA{GGGACCAATGCG}
  \DNA{TTATCCAATCTC}

\stoptext
```

The advantage of using Lua is that you don't have to mess around with catcodes.

Answer (score 4):

New solution, with a parser.

Using core TeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\def\dnaA{\textcolor{red}{A}}
\def\dnaT{\textcolor{green}{T}}
\def\dnaC{\textcolor{blue}{C}}
\def\dnaG{\textcolor{black}{G}}
\def\DNA#1{%
  \edef\testchar{#1}%
  \if;\testchar
    \relax
  \else
    \csname dna#1\endcsname
    \expandafter\DNA
  \fi}
\begin{document}
\DNA ACGTAGCTAACCG;
\end{document}
```

Using `pgf`'s `parser` module:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepgfmodule{parser}
\pgfparserdef{dna}{initial}{\meaning A}{\textcolor{red}{A}}
\pgfparserdef{dna}{initial}{\meaning T}{\textcolor{green}{T}}
\pgfparserdef{dna}{initial}{\meaning C}{\textcolor{blue}{C}}
\pgfparserdef{dna}{initial}{\meaning G}{\textcolor{black}{G}}
\pgfparserdef{dna}{initial}{\meaning ;}{\pgfparserswitch{final}}
\newcommand\DNA{\pgfparserparse{dna}}
\begin{document}
\DNA ACGTAGCTAACCG;
\end{document}
```

[image]