# Underlining a coloured DNA sequence

Tags: formatting, color, verbatim

In the posts to the question of Timtico ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16572/typesetting-different-characters-with-different-colors-in-a-dna-sequence)) several ways have been proposed to colour the As,Ts,Cs and Gs differently within a DNA sequence. What I want is also to be able to underline some nucleotides to emphasise them, e.g.: \dna{ATACAG$\underbar{AG}$CATA} but I didn't manage to do so.
Does anyone have suggestions to this problem?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you want to underline a specific subsequence like `AG`? Not everyone here is a biologist. Please describe your question without many professional terms, and provide some examples/pictures to illustrate the question.

Comment: You might want to have a look at the [`texshade`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/texshade) package (Typesetting nucleotide and peptide alignments) and maybe also [`textopo`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/textopo) (for shaded membrane protein topology plots) by the same author.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added a delimiter to the code from my answer at [typesetting different characters with different colors in a DNA sequence](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16572/typesetting-different-characters-with-different-colors-in-a-dna-sequence)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,xcolor}
\lstdefinestyle{dna}{%
    literate={A}{\textcolor{green}{A}}{1}
        {B}{\textcolor{blue}{B}}{1}
        {C}{\textcolor{red}{C}}{1}
        {a}{\textcolor{green}{A}}{1}
        {b}{\textcolor{blue}{B}}{1}
        {c}{\textcolor{red}{C}}{1},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    moredelim=[is][\underline]{_}{_}
}
\newcommand{\DNA}[1]{%
    \lstinline[style=dna]{#1}%
}
\begin{document}
\DNA{AA_CAAAD_A}
\end{document}
```

The result is
[image: result of the above code]

I think, this should work for you.

Comment: Wow, that was indeed what I was looking for. 
Thank you very much!!

Comment: @Ros Your welcome :-D

Comment: One additional question: would it also be possible to write the literate shorter? (That would be handy when colouring protein sequences, for which multiple letters have to be the same colour). E.g. something like this:
literate={A,B,C,D}{\textcolor{green}{\1}}{1},
{E,F,G,H}{\textcolor{blue}{\1}}{1}
etc..

Comment: @Ros: I don’t believe that there is a way to do it with `listings`. Maybe the manual can give you more information. ps. Note that there’s no comma `,` between the literate definitions.