# Visualization in LaTeX of hamming distance

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks

I have for example the following two strings:

```
 1: 00101101
 2: 00100100
```

I would like that each number will be place in a box and the boxes with the number one should be higher then the ones with zero.

example:

```
 ---------------------------------
 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
 --------|   |---|   |   |---|   |
         -----   ---------   -----


         -----       -----
 --------|   |-------|   |--------
 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
 ---------------------------------
```

Later on I would like to play with the colors, between boxes which doesn't contain the same number.

I would like some help how to create the boxes.

**EDIT**
It seems that my question was not so clear. I would like that the 'box' of 1 or 0 will not be shifted, but the 'box' of 1 will be simply bigger....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can construct a macro that iterates over input, reading one token at a time. Then you compare the token to `0` or `1` and decide what to do. The commands `\zero` and `\one` are responsible for the actual typesetting.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\zero}{\fbox{\textcolor{red}{0}}}
\newcommand{\onea}{\fbox{\rule{0pt}{1em}\textcolor{blue}{1}}}
\newcommand{\oneb}{\fbox{\rule[\heightof{1}-1em]{0pt}{\heightof{1}}\textcolor{blue}{1}}}

\newcommand{\process}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \def\next##1{%
      \ifx##1\relax
        \let\next=\relax
      \else
        \if0##1%
          \zero
        \else\if1##1%
          \one
        \else
          unknown
        \fi\fi
      \fi
      \next}%
    \next #1\relax
  \endgroup}
\newcommand{\processa}{\let\one=\onea \process}
\newcommand{\processb}{\let\one=\oneb \process}

\begin{document}

Test: \processa{101010}

Test: \processb{101010}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: By the way, the `0.5ex` and color choice similarity to Peter Grill's answer is not on purpose :-)

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution using the [listings package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/). Is this close to what you want?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\lstdefinestyle{hama}{%
    literate={1}{\raisebox{0.5ex}{\fbox{\textcolor{blue}{1}}}}{1}%
        {0}{\fbox{\textcolor{red}{0}}}{1},%
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,%
}
\lstdefinestyle{hamb}{%
    literate={0}{\raisebox{0.5ex}{\fbox{\textcolor{blue}{0}}}}{1}%
        {1}{\fbox{\textcolor{red}{1}}}{1},%
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,%
}

\newcommand{\HAMA}[1]{%
    \lstinline[style=hama]{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\HAMB}[1]{%
    \lstinline[style=hamb]{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
\HAMA{00101101}

\HAMB{00100100}
\end{document}
```

This solution is adapted this question [typesetting different characters with different colors in a DNA sequence](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16572/typesetting-different-characters-with-different-colors-in-a-dna-sequence), which also has several other methods which may be helpful.

Comment: yes it is close to what i wanted, but not exactly. I would like that the number will not shifted in 0.5ex in case it is a 1 from 0, but that when it is a number 1, the box will be bigger.

Answer (score 5):

there are three optional arguments: `<position> <color 0> <color 1>`.
they are counted from the *left*, if you want to define the `<color 1>` then you have to specify the two in front, too.

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{xcolor}
\makeatletter
\def\0{\fbox{\textcolor{\process@colA}{0}}}
\def\1{\fbox{\process@rule\textcolor{\process@colB}{1}}}
\def\process@iv#1{%
  \begingroup
   \def\next##1{%
      \ifx##1\relax
        \let\next=\relax
      \else
        \ifx0##1\0\else\ifx1##1\1\else?\fi\fi
      \fi
      \next}%
    \next #1\relax
  \endgroup}
\def\process{\@ifnextchar[\process@i{\process@iii[b][red][blue]}}
\def\process@i[#1]{\@ifnextchar[{\process@ii[#1]}{\process@iii[#1][red][blue]}}
\def\process@ii[#1][#2]{\@ifnextchar[{\process@iii[#1][#2]}{\process@iii[#1][#2][blue]}}
\def\process@iii[#1][#2][#3]{%
  \ifx#1b\def\process@rule{\rule{0pt}{3ex}}%
  \else\def\process@rule{\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{2ex}}\fi%
  \def\process@colA{#2}%
  \def\process@colB{#3}%
  \process@iv}
\makeatother   
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}

Test: \process{101010}\\
Test: \process[t]{101010}\\
Test: \process[b][yellow][cyan!80!blue]{101010}\\
Test: \process[t][magenta][gray]{101010}\\
Test  \process{100200}

\end{document}
```

[image]