# Problem with the alignment of characters

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I am having some trouble in displaying  characters in LaTeX. Here is what I am doing.

I am performing a binary addition and would like to have all the characters aligned one below the other.

Here is the small example :

```
1010
1000 
----
0010
```

However, the problem I am facing is that the characters are not aligned in a vertical line. If it was a table, I could align left-edge or right edge, but not here.

I would prefer, here, 1-1-0, 0-0-0, 1-0-1, 0-0-0 are aligned in a single line vertically.

I am trying to give proper spacing, but it does not look elegant in the pdf. It looks misaligned with a long sequence of binary number.

P.S : Attached is the screen shot of the pdf file. 
[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside,english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\newdimen\digitwidth 
\settowidth\digitwidth{0} 
\def~{\hspace{\digitwidth}}
\def\divrule#1#2{% 
\noalign{\moveright#1\digitwidth% 
\vbox{\hrule width#2\digitwidth}}} 
\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}r@{}} 
%10010 
\\ \hline 
\big|\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}} 
1010 1111\\ 
1000 1000 \\ 
\divrule{0}{10} 
~~ 1000 1000 \\ 
\end{tabular} 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you try using a fixed width font?

Comment: Characters that are aligned on a vertical line share the same *horizontal* alignment. (And yes, it took me some time to figure this out. `:-)`)

Comment: Yes, I am using the default font.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps defining a new environment

```
\newlength{\digitwidth}
\newcommand\divrule[2]{\noalign{\moveright#1\digitwidth\vbox{\hrule width#2\digitwidth}}}
\newenvironment{bdivision}[1]
  {\settowidth\digitwidth{0}\setlength{\tabcolsep}{\digitwidth}%
   \def~{\hspace{\digitwidth}}%
   \hphantom{#1~\vrule}\begin{tabular}{l@{}}
   \hline\relax\llap{#1~\vrule\strut\hspace{\tabcolsep}\kern-0.4pt}\ignorespaces}
  {\end{tabular}}
```

and inputting data as

```
\begin{bdivision}{10010}
1010~1111~1111~1111~0000~0010\\
1000~1000~0001~0000~1 \\
\divrule{1}{21}
~~10~0111~1110~1111~100 \\
~~10~0010~0000~0100~001 \\
\divrule{3}{27}
~~~~~~101~1110~1011~1010~00
\end{bdivision}
```

(the digits are almost at random, but this should be the idea).

[image]

Comment: Very nice and intuitive to use!

Comment: Amazing, works really nice :)

Answer (score 4):

**Update (old solution moved to bottom)**

Now that I MWE was provided, I think one way to do this is to adapt the solution from [Visualization in LaTeX of hamming distance](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28735/visualization-in-latex-of-hamming-distance/28738#28738) which used [the `listings` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/) and define a style that iterates over each character.

Each character is set in the width of the digit `0`, and other properties can be adjusted based on the character, such as changing the color of the digits separately if you want.  For normal math purposes you can just remove the color change code.

One problem that comes about is the leading spacing as TeX wants to gobble that up. For this, I adapted your solution by replacing a `~` with a space of the appropriate width.  This only needs to be inserted for leading spaces.  Any spaces after the first binary digit can just be a normal space (or a `~`).

With this solution, the use of the `\ttfamily` is optional, since each digit (and space) is set to be the width of a 0, but the output looked the better with `\ttfamily` and the image shown reflects that.

[image]

Here is the modified version of your code:

```
\documentclass[twoside,english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}% can remove this if you don't want color in output

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

\newdimen\digitwidth%
\settowidth\digitwidth{0}%
\def~{\hspace{\digitwidth}}%
\def\divrule#1#2{%
\noalign{\moveright#1\digitwidth% 
\vbox{\hrule width#2\digitwidth}}}%

\newcommand*{\Resize}[1]{\makebox[\digitwidth]{#1}}%
\lstdefinestyle{BinaryNumber}{%
    literate={1}{\textcolor{blue}{\Resize{1}}}{1}%
             {0}{\textcolor{red}{\Resize{0}}}{1}%
             {,}{\Resize{\phantom{ }}}{1}%
             {\ }{\Resize{\phantom{ }}}{1},%
   basicstyle=\ttfamily,%  Optional to use this
}
\newcommand{\Binary}[1]{%
    \lstinline[style=BinaryNumber]{#1}%
}


\begin{document}
\Binary{10010}
\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}r@{}} 
\\ \hline 
\big|%
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}} 
\Binary{1010 1111}\\ 
\Binary{1000 1000}\\ 
\divrule{0}{10} 
\Binary{,,,1 0000 1000} \\ 
\end{tabular} 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

---

**Old Solution:**

Does this produces the results you ask for:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document}
With textt:
\texttt{\newline%
1010\newline
1000\newline
----\newline
0010\newline
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes it does, But, if the binary sequence has a space in between, the alignment is lost :( Please have a look at the screen shot

Comment: It'd be easier if you would just post a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: Adding spaces does not seem to effect the example code provided here. Things still line up.  It appears from your new image that the issue is with the vertical line shifting the alignment, not the characters.  If you post a MWE can help more.

Comment: Definitely, I am attaching the working example

Comment: Thanks. Now that I know what you want I can proceed. I have an idea for a good solution for you...

Comment: Revised solution based on your MWE provided.

Comment: Thnak you so much for your help  :) It works really nice : )

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple of options here:

- Using a `tabular`; yes, this is possible:

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{*{4}{@{}c@{}}}% 4 centered columns without interspaced gaps
    1&0&1&0 \\
    1&0&0&0 \\ \hline
    0&0&1&0
  \end{tabular}
  \end{document}
  ```

  [image: tabular for binary addition]

  Extending this to incorporate more than just a 4-bit binary addition is also possible. Using the [`array` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/array) to define a new column type `B`, we have:

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array
  \newcolumntype{B}{*{4}{@{}c@{}}}% One byte/4 bits
  \begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{B@{~}B@{~}B@{~}B@{~}B}% 5 centered bytes with ~ as gaps
    1&0&1&0 & 1&1&1&1 & 1&1&1&1 & 1&1&1&1 & 0&0&0&0 \\
    1&0&0&0 & 1&0&0&0 & 0&0&0&1 & 0&0&0&0 & 1&1&0&1 \\ \hline
    0&0&1&1 & 1&0&0&0 & 0&0&0&0 & 1&1&1&1 & 1&1&0&1
  \end{tabular}
  \end{document}
  ```

  [image: larger binary addition]
- Or you could fix the character width by using a mono-spaced font:

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \begin{document}
  {\noindent\ttfamily
    1010 \\
    1000 \\
    ---- \\
    0010
  }
  \end{document}
  ```

  ​[image: mono-spaced font "table"]

  You could also use this mono-spaced in a `tabular` for better horizontal line representation, thereby combining the aforementioned examples:

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \begin{document}
  \ttfamily\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
    1010 \\
    1000 \\ \hline
    0010
  \end{tabular}
  \end{document}
  ```

  [image: mono-spaced tabular]

Similar extensions to larger binary additions are also possible for the last two examples that use mono-spaced `\ttfamily`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I am trying you first approach. If I insert just space, the binary sequences are not aligned on a vertical line. with & character, it is working pretty fine. Thank you. BTW, I tried with "~" as well. I am not an expert in this.

Comment: Inserting a space at the end would cause a problem, for sure. That is because you're increasing the width of the final element. You would have to modify the `tabular` column specification for this. I'll update my answer to include something like this, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you want, so here's some suggestions.

### Matrices

Maybe you'll be happy using matrices as in:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{matrix}
  1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  \hline
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{matrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: A matrix]

If you want more options check out [`mathtools`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools).

### Verbatim

The following is probably not what you want and it's not pretty. The idea is just throw everything in `verbatim`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
1010
1000 
----
0010
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image: Verbatim digits]