# Listings package: How can I format all numbers?

Tags: listings, color

I want to highlight all the numbers appearing in an input code of a certain program by, for example, coloring them. By numbers I mean integer, rational and floating point numbers. I am trying with the [listings](ftp://ftp.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) page but with no success. I have noticed that specific numbers can be formatted with the `morekeywords` and `alsoletter` options on defining the language but I want to acomplish this task for any number.

For example, I would like the code

```
vector([3/5,4,0.4566])
```

to appear with the three numbers with color green (or whatever). Is it possible to do this in an automatic way?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Even though it may seem trivial, it is always best to compose a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 24):

Similar to solutions in [Visualization in LaTeX of hamming distance](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28735/visualization-in-latex-of-hamming-distance/28738#28738), and [Problem with the alignment of characters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29959/problem-with-the-alignment-of-characters/29962#29962), you could use the `literate` command to define a style that is to be applied to each digit. Below I included a color for the `.` but commented out the color for the `,`.

[image]

As there might be a period used outside of a number context, I have defined different styles based on the assumption that any period used in a number will have a digit following it.

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand*{\FormatDigit}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
\lstdefinestyle{FormattedNumber}{%
    literate={0}{{\FormatDigit{0}}}{1}%
             {1}{{\FormatDigit{1}}}{1}%
             {2}{{\FormatDigit{2}}}{1}%
             {3}{{\FormatDigit{3}}}{1}%
             {4}{{\FormatDigit{4}}}{1}%
             {5}{{\FormatDigit{5}}}{1}%
             {6}{{\FormatDigit{6}}}{1}%
             {7}{{\FormatDigit{7}}}{1}%
             {8}{{\FormatDigit{8}}}{1}%
             {9}{{\FormatDigit{9}}}{1}%
             {.0}{{\FormatDigit{.0}}}{2}% Following is to ensure that only periods
             {.1}{{\FormatDigit{.1}}}{2}% followed by a digit are changed.
             {.2}{{\FormatDigit{.2}}}{2}%
             {.3}{{\FormatDigit{.3}}}{2}%
             {.4}{{\FormatDigit{.4}}}{2}%
             {.5}{{\FormatDigit{.5}}}{2}%
             {.6}{{\FormatDigit{.6}}}{2}%
             {.7}{{\FormatDigit{.7}}}{2}%
             {.8}{{\FormatDigit{.8}}}{2}%
             {.9}{{\FormatDigit{.9}}}{2}%
             %{,}{{\FormatDigit{,}}{1}% depends if you want the "," in color
             {\ }{{ }}{1}% handle the space
             ,
   basicstyle=\ttfamily,%  Optional to use this
}
\newcommand{\FormattedNumber}[1]{%
    \lstinline[style=FormattedNumber]{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
\FormattedNumber{a.vector([3/5,4,0.4566])}
\end{document}
```

Comment: One caveat: This would format `\FormattedNumber{a.vector(<stuff>)}` by also making the period `blue`. It would be possible, but somewhat round-about to get that fixed using `mathescape=true` and then using `\FormattedNumber{a$.$vector(<stuff>)}`.

Comment: @Werner: Excellent point. Have updated the solution to handle that case.

Comment: That's perfect!!! You saved me a lot of time. Thank you!!!

Comment: All replacements that include the comma should have 2 instead of 1 at the end. this defines the number of output characters and is important for the complicated spacing of listings.

Comment: @PeterGrill excellent solution! Only caveat for me is that it still highlights integers, even when they are commented. Is there a way to correct this?

Comment: @Majoko: Perhaps the solution at [Coloring digits with the listings package](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34896/coloring-digits-with-the-listings-package/) is more helpful. If that does not resolve your question I would suggest you asked a new question with including a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.  You can reference these questions if you are adapting the code from them.