# RGB colour macro: is it possible to divide by 255 in Latex?

Tags: macros, color

I'm fiddling with source code display (Objective-C) and the listings package. I want to colour comments the same green that appears in XCode. I determined that it has an RGB value of 67, 133, 34. To use this I need to divide by 255 since this is the format/value range of input parameters to

```
\definecolor{green}{rgb}{0.34,0.52,0.14}
```

Is there any way to write a macro in latex that divides by 255? Thanks.

In response to comment:

If I do

```
\usepackage{listings} % For source code display.
\usepackage{courier} % For source code display.
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset{basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily}
\lstset{language=[Objective]C}
\definecolor{green}{rgb}{67,133,34}
\lstset{commentstyle=\color{green}}
```

instead of

```
\usepackage{listings} % For source code display.
\usepackage{courier} % For source code display.
\usepackage{color}

\lstset{basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily}
\lstset{language=[Objective]C}
\definecolor{green}{rgb}{0.34,0.52,0.14}
\lstset{commentstyle=\color{green}}
```

the comment in my source code listing vanishes.

Comment: With the `xcolor` package you can use `\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{67,133,34}`

Comment: @egreg Thank you. If I do that it makes the comment in my source code listing vanish.

Comment: @MattN.: You have to use capital letters (`RGB`) to define colours using values from 0-255.

Comment: And I wouldn't redefine `green`, also.

Comment: @Jake Indeed! I didn't know, thank you!

Comment: It now works, thank you very much egreg and Jake for your help!

Comment: Talk about design decisions the `rgb` vs `RGB` had me pulling out my hair a bit.

Comment: @AFeldman Well, as long as it's just ''a bit'' and you're not completely bald now... ; )

Comment: Yes, just a little...I no longer have eyebrows.

Comment: Related question, [Color RGB in LaTeX - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239461/color-rgb-in-latex/239463#239463)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

With the package `xcolor` you can define colors using the range 0–255 with the RGB color model:

```
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{67,133,34}
```

(notice the uppercase letters). A more complicated way using `color` would be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\defineRGBcolor}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \def\color@values{\@gobble}%
  \@for\next:=#2\do{%
    \count0=\next\relax
    \multiply\count0 100
    \divide\count0 255
    \edef\color@values{\color@values,0.\number\count0}%
  }%
  \edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\definecolor{#1}{rgb}{\color@values}}\x
}
\makeatother
\defineRGBcolor{agreen}{67, 133, 34}
\definecolor{bgreen}{rgb}{0.26,0.52,0.13}
\begin{document}
\textcolor{agreen}{ABCDEF}

\textcolor{bgreen}{ABCDEF}
\end{document}
```

The rgb value 0.26,0.52,0.13 is what really corresponds to 67,133,34 dividing by 255.

Comment: Thank you very much! Btw, do you by any chance know how to colour numbers (numerical constants) in source code listings using the listings package? I didn't find out how and now I suspect it might be impossible. (unless I write my own listings package?)

Comment: @MattN. That's a very different question. I believe there's something on the site.

Comment: @MattN. You can find it here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32176/24276

Comment: you can use the same `RGB` syntax in the original `color` package as well in most back end drivers. (All of the original ones at least).