# \lstset colorize numbers in code

Tags: color, listings, code

I defined a syntax highlighting for my code like so:

```
\lstdefinelanguage{CSharp}{
    sensitive = true,
    keywords={assembly, class, method, field},
    keywords=[2]{public, private, family, assembly, famandassem, famorassem, nested, static, abstract, virtual, hidebysig, cil, managed, specialname, rtspecialname, interface, sealed, auto, ansi, unicode, beforefieldinit, sequential, explicit},
    keywords=[3]{class, void, string, int, object, if, else, if, switch, break, case, boo, while, truel},
    keywordstyle=\color{forestgreen},
    keywordstyle=[2]\color{purple},
    keywordstyle=[3]\color{blue},
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\scriptsize,
    stepnumber=1,
    numbersep=8pt,
    xleftmargin=2em,
    framexleftmargin=1.5em,
    showstringspaces=false,
    breaklines=true,
    frame=single,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    comment=[l]{//},
    morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},
    commentstyle=\color{forestgreen},
    stringstyle=\color{maroon},
    morestring=[b]',
    morestring=[b]"
}

\definecolor{forestgreen}{rgb}{0.13, 0.55, 0.13}
\definecolor{maroon}{rgb}{0.5, 0.0, 0.0}

\newcommand{\sourcecode}[3]{\vspace{10pt}\lstinputlisting[language=CSharp, label={#2}, caption={#3}, captionpos=b, abovecaptionskip=10pt]{#1}}
```

It works nicely but I can't change the colors of numbers in the code. When I add them to the keyword list they are simply ignored. And modifying the numberstyle only affects the line numbers but not the numbers in the code:

[image]

How can I set custom color highlighting for numbers in the code, such as the `0` and the `3`?

Comment: Possibly duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32176/31034

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). It is much easier to help you if we can start with some compilable code that illustrates your problem. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, include any necessary packages and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. At the moment we have to guess what packages etc you are using before we can compile your code.

Comment: There are already several similar questions on this site, additionally to the one linked above [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34896/coloring-digits-with-the-listings-package) or [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/217505/listings-color-numbers-only-out-of-keywords).