# Is this possible to fix the numbers always in roman using listing

Tags: listings, roman-numerals

My tags are follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{textcomp,listings}%

\lstnewenvironment{python}[1][]{%
\lstset{%
mathescape=false,%
language=python,%
basicstyle=\ttfamily\normalsize,%
otherkeywords={*,\{, \} },%
keywordstyle=\color{black},%
stringstyle=\color{black},%
showstringspaces=false,%
emph={class, pass, in, for, while, if, is, elif, else, not, and, or,%
def, print, exec, break, continue, return},%
emphstyle=\color{black}\bfseries,%
emph={[3]True, False, None, self},%
emphstyle=[2]\color{black!10},%
emph={[3]from, import, as},%
emphstyle=[3]\color{black},%
upquote=true,%
morecomment=[s]{"""}{"""},%
commentstyle=\color{gray}\slshape,%
aboveskip=12pt,belowskip=12pt,xleftmargin=-2pt,xrightmargin=3pt,framexleftmargin=20pt,framextopmargin=1pt,%
rulesepcolor=\color{gray},#1%
}}{}%

\begin{document}

\begin{python}
In [7]: np.searchsorted(X, 0.5)
Out[7]: 4998210 # This is 1 for test 1000
\end{python}

\begin{python}
In [7]: np.searchsorted(X, 0.5) # left edge 1234567890

 from scipy import stats
    dist stats.uniform (0, 2)  # left edge 0, width  2
\end{python}

\end{document}
```

It is working fine without issues. Please confirm that I need the `arabic numerals (i.e., 0 to 9)` should be in `roman` always, refer the screen shot:

[image]

Is this possible to fix? Please advise...

Comment: Do you want the numbers to be in roman font only in comments or everywhere?

Comment: @siracusa Thanks for your attention. Other places it comes correctly (in `roman font`), but in the commented text it comes in `italic`, but I need those to be in `roman`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that makes use of the general number highlighting approach presented in [Listings: color numbers only out of keywords](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/500806/23765).

We need to make some changes to the `OutputOther` hook from that solution, because in this case you want to override the default style no matter whether you are in a comment or not. The new hook looks like:

```
\lst@AddToHook{OutputOther}{%
    \lst@ifparsenumbers
        \expandafter\@hook@ifnumber\the\lst@token\@end {%
            \let\orig@thestyle=\lst@thestyle
            \def\lst@thestyle{\orig@thestyle\lst@numbersstyle}%
        }{}%
    \fi
}
```

Also to your `\lstset` command the following lines have to be added:

```
parsenumbers=true,
numbersstyle=\upshape
```

Wherever a number is then parsed by `listings` in the input, the `numbersstyle` is added to the currently active style.

---

Full example code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{textcomp,listings}%


\makeatletter

%%% Copied from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/500690/23765
% Some conditional tests
\def\@genericif#1{#1\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi}
\def\@ifdigit#1{\@genericif{\ifnum1<1\noexpand#1\relax}}
\def\@ifempty#1{\@genericif{\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax}}

% The main parsing macros
\def\parse@num#1{%
    \@ifempty{#1}%
        {\parse@num@false}%
        {\@genericif{\parsesign}%
            {\parse@num@sign#1{}\@end}%
            {\parse@num@dig#1{}\@end}%
        }%
}
% Parse sign
\def\parse@num@sign#1#2\@end{%
    \@genericif{\ifx\parse@num@minus#1}%
        {\@ifempty{#2}{\parse@num@false}{\parse@num@dig#2\@end}}%
        {\@genericif{\ifx\parse@num@plus#1}%
            {\@ifempty{#2}{\parse@num@false}{\parse@num@dig#2\@end}}%
            {\parse@num@dig#1#2\@end}%
        }%
}
% Parse first digit
\def\parse@num@dig#1#2\@end{%
    \@ifdigit{#1}%
        {\@ifempty{#2}{\parse@num@true}{\parse@num@digs#2\@end}}%
        {\parse@num@false}%
}
% Parse optional following digits
\def\parse@num@digs#1#2\@end{%
    \@ifdigit{#1}{%
        \@ifempty{#2}%
            {\parse@num@true}%
            {\parse@num@digs#2\@end}%
    }{%
        \@genericif{\parsefloat}{%
            \@genericif{\ifx\parse@num@point#1}%
                {\@ifempty{#2}{\parse@num@false}{\parse@num@decs#2\@end}}%
                {\parse@num@false}%
        }{\parse@num@false}%
    }%
}
% Parse decimal places
\def\parse@num@decs#1#2\@end{%
    \@ifdigit{#1}{%
        \@ifempty{#2}%
            {\parse@num@true}%
            {\parse@num@decs#2\@end}%
    }{\parse@num@false}%
}

% User interface
\newcommand\ifnumber[4][]{%
    \begingroup
    \let\parsesign=\iftrue
    \let\parsefloat=\iftrue
    \let\parse@num@minus=-%
    \let\parse@num@plus=+%
    \let\parse@num@point=.%
    #1%
    \def\parse@num@true{\endgroup#3}%
    \def\parse@num@false{\endgroup#4}%
    \parse@num{#2}%
}   


%%% Additions to the listings package
\lst@Key{numbersstyle}{}{\def\lst@numbersstyle{#1}}
\lst@Key{parsenumbers}{false}[t]{\lstKV@SetIf{#1}\lst@ifparsenumbers}

\lst@AddToHook{OutputOther}{%
    \lst@ifparsenumbers
        \expandafter\@hook@ifnumber\the\lst@token\@end {%
            \let\orig@thestyle=\lst@thestyle
            \def\lst@thestyle{\orig@thestyle\lst@numbersstyle}%
        }{}%
    \fi
}
\def\@hook@ifnumber#1#2\@end{%
    \@genericif{\ifx\lst@nolig#1}%
        {\@hook@ifnumber@{#2}}%
        {\@hook@ifnumber@{#1#2}}%
}
\def\@hook@ifnumber@{%
    \ifnumber[\expandafter\let\expandafter\parse@num@minus\csname lst@um-\endcsname]%
}

\makeatother


\lstnewenvironment{python}[1][]{%
\lstset{%
mathescape=false,%
language=python,%
basicstyle=\ttfamily\normalsize,%
otherkeywords={*,\{, \} },%
keywordstyle=\color{black},%
stringstyle=\color{black},%
showstringspaces=false,%
emph={class, pass, in, for, while, if, is, elif, else, not, and, or,%
def, print, exec, break, continue, return},%
emphstyle=\color{black}\bfseries,%
emph={[3]True, False, None, self},%
emphstyle=[2]\color{black!10},%
emph={[3]from, import, as},%
emphstyle=[3]\color{black},%
upquote=true,%
morecomment=[s]{"""}{"""},%
commentstyle=\color{gray}\slshape,%
aboveskip=12pt,belowskip=12pt,xleftmargin=-2pt,xrightmargin=3pt,framexleftmargin=20pt,framextopmargin=1pt,%
rulesepcolor=\color{gray},#1,
parsenumbers=true,
numbersstyle=\upshape
}}{}%

\begin{document}

\begin{python}
In [7]: np.searchsorted(X, 0.5)
Out[7]: 4998210 # This is 1 for test 1000
"""
Some text 1234
"""
\end{python}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**EDIT:** The problem of the `0` not showing up in upright font is due to the fact that `listings` parses `0` and `,` as one unit (as both have codes *digit* or *other*). The `OutputOther` hook then tries to parse `0,` as a number which fails and thus doesn't give the expected font.

As a workaround you can add the following line to the `\lstset` command:

```
literate={,}{{\char`\,}}{1}
```

which outputs

[image]

This makes the parser break before it reads the comma. In this special case there should be no side-effects, because commas shouldn't be part of keywords or other special syntax elements. Unfortunately, `listings` makes it hard to add the processing of new syntax elements, so working around one problem here often raises another one there.

Comment: Wow, such a great reply...much thankful to you....

Comment: If I try second `python` text, `\begin{python}
In [7]: np.searchsorted(X, 0.5) # left edge 1234567890

 from scipy import stats
    dist stats.uniform (0, 2)  # left edge 0, width  2
\end{python}` 0 and 2 comes in italic which comes at the last line, any thing mistake I did? Please advise...

Comment: I've updated my question too...

Comment: Just now realised that comma between characters affected this error, is this possible to fix? advise please...

Comment: @MadyYuvi Please see the update

Comment: Sorry to disturb again and again; now the problem with numbers comes in square brackets, i.e., if a line  `In [14]: x = np.arange(1, 4)  # [1, 2, 3]` then the digits comes in italic, how to fix it? please advise....

Comment: @MadyYuvi You can add more entries to the `literate` option, in this case for `[` and `]`, i.e. ```literate={,}{{\char`\,}}{1} {[}{{\char`\[}}{1} {]}{{\char`\]}}{1}```.

Comment: Yes, it helps to fix it, sorry, after sent the message only I realised that, anyhow, thanks a lot....