# How to fix column alignment in lstlisting with columns=fixed and color?

Tags: spacing, color, vertical-alignment, listings

I am using the `listings` package to align some fixed-width text under an image. Font `basicstyle=\ttfamily` with `columns=fixed` has a nice look and perfect spacing.

There are two issues with column alignment inside `lstlisting`:

A small part of text needs to be a different color (here: orange). This text is not separated from other text by white space. Apparently, the escape characters inside `lstlisting` are treated as space, which messes up alignment in the middle. **[1 in image below.]**

There is a slight alignment mismatch between lines with a different number of spaces between words. **[2 in image below.]**

Looking at the [package documentation](http://mirror.physik-pool.tu-berlin.de/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf), I tried to no avail to combine `columns=fullflexible` with `keepspaces=true` and `basewidth=0.6em`. Any other ideas would me highly appreciated!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\noindent\framebox[7.1cm]{image}

\def\coloro{\color{orange}}
\def\colorb{\color{black}}
\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\ttfamily,escapeinside={(}{)},columns=fixed]
|  ||  ||  ||  ||  ||  ||  ||  |
(\aftergroup\coloro)||||||||||||||||(\aftergroup\colorb)||||||||||||||||
||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
|| || || || || || || || || || ||
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here. First, don't use `escapeinside` for highlighting parts of the listing, but set up a proper delimited environment instead:

```
moredelim=[is][\color{orange}]{(}{)},
```

This defines a new environment delimited by `(` and `)` with invisible delimiters. As opposed to `escapeinside` all typesetting is done inside the listing's special parsing environment, while the `escape` options switch back to normal LaTeX mode temporarily.

The other issue is due to a bug in the `listings` package which seems to align space tokens and other tokens differently even in `fixed` column alignment. To circumvent this problem you can use the `literate` option to map `|` to itself:

```
literate={|}{|}1
```

Subsequent pipe characters aren't grouped then and alignment is correct.

Full example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\noindent\framebox[7.1cm]{image}

\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    moredelim=[is][\color{orange}]{(}{)},
    columns=fixed,
    literate={|}{|}1
}

\begin{lstlisting}
|  ||  ||  ||  ||  ||  ||  ||  |
(||||||||||||||||)||||||||||||||||
||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
|| || || || || || || || || || ||
||||||||||||||||
                ||||||||||||||||
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]