# "Isodat" language source code syntax highlighting

Tags: listings, color

Isodat language is used for Mass-spectrometers from ThermoFisher Scientific®, which is used for Stable Isotope Mass-spectrometry.

Parts of the language's syntax highlighting has been explored in [listings package: formating all numbers in language definition?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109377/listings-package-formating-all-numbers-in-language-definition) and the follow-up question [listing package: colored numbers, but not colored in variable names](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109439/listing-package-colored-numbers-but-not-colored-in-variable-names).

In the end it should look like the image below:

[image: Example of Isodat source code.]

I get the following:

[image: .png of .pdf from .tex.]

Do you know what needs to be changed here? The problems are:
1. numbers within comment,
2. numbers within string,

So far the following have been fixed:
3. keywords in blue (if, else, string, number),
4. parenthesis following keywords in black,
5. block comments,
6. keywords in lightblue.
7. strings in blue

```
\documentclass[fleqn, a4paper, landscape]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{isored}{rgb}{0.6,0,0} % for strings
\definecolor{isogreen}{rgb}{0.25,0.6,0.2} % comments
\definecolor{isoblue}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,1} % keyword
\definecolor{isolightblue}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,1.0} % keywords
\definecolor{isocomgreen}{rgb}{0.25,0.35,0.75} % javadoc

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newtoggle{InString}{}% Keep track of if we are within a string
\togglefalse{InString}% Assume not initally in string
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34896/coloring-digits-with-the-listings-package?rq=1
\newcommand*{\ColorIfNotInString}[1]{\iftoggle{InString}{#1}{\textcolor{isored}#1}}%
\newcommand*{\ProcessQuote}[1]{#1\iftoggle{InString}{\global\togglefalse{InString}}{\global\toggletrue{InString}}}%

\usepackage{listings} 

\lstdefinelanguage{isodat}
{%
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,%
  literate=%
     %{"}{{{\ProcessQuote{"}}}}1% Disable coloring within double quotes
     {0}{{\ColorIfNotInString{0}}}{1}%
     {1}{{\ColorIfNotInString{1}}}{1}%
     {2}{{\ColorIfNotInString{2}}}{1}%
     {3}{{\ColorIfNotInString{3}}}{1}%
     {4}{{\ColorIfNotInString{4}}}{1}%
     {5}{{\ColorIfNotInString{5}}}{1}%
     {6}{{\ColorIfNotInString{6}}}{1}%
     {7}{{\ColorIfNotInString{7}}}{1}%
     {8}{{\ColorIfNotInString{8}}}{1}%
     {9}{{\ColorIfNotInString{9}}}{1}%
     {.0}{{\ColorIfNotInString{.0}}}{1}% Following is to ensure that only periods
     {.1}{{\ColorIfNotInString{.1}}}{1}% followed by a digit are changed.
     {.2}{{\ColorIfNotInString{.2}}}{1}%
     {.3}{{\ColorIfNotInString{.3}}}{1}%
     {.4}{{\ColorIfNotInString{.4}}}{1}%
     {.5}{{\ColorIfNotInString{.5}}}{1}%
     {.6}{{\ColorIfNotInString{.6}}}{1}%
     {.7}{{\ColorIfNotInString{.7}}}{1}%
     {.8}{{\ColorIfNotInString{.8}}}{1}%
     {.9}{{\ColorIfNotInString{.9}}}{1}%
     {\ }{{ }}{1}% handle the space
     ,
     %string=[s]{_}{=},
     %string=[s]{_}{(}, 
  mathescape=true, 
  emphstyle={[2]\color{isoblue}},
  tabsize=4,
  captionpos=b,
  showstringspaces=false,
  keywordstyle=\color{isoblue},
  keywordstyle=[2]\color{isoblue},
  commentstyle=\color{isogreen},%
  stringstyle=\color{isolightblue},%
  morestring=[s][\color{isoblue}]{"}{"},%
  morecomment = [l]{//},
  morecomment = [l]{///},
  morecomment = [s]{/*}{*/},
  sensitive = true,
  morekeywords = {if, else, string, number},%You need to add here
  emph={_Set, _Delay, _strstr, _strtod, _strmid},% You need to add here
  emphstyle=\color{isolightblue},
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{lstlisting}[caption=Isodat language sample..,language=isodat]

        _Set("Precon/Trap 3",0);
        _Delay(1000,1,"Evacuating Carbon trap")
        //_Set("ExtValveBlock/Valve 4",1); commented because interferes with extraction

        string SeqPrepText="";
        number AnzFull=1;

        SeqPrepText =_GetSequenceText("Preparation","1,0");
        //_MessageBox(SeqPrepText,MB_OK,MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);        

        Midpoint    = _strstr (SeqPrepText,",");
        if (Midpoint==-1) 
        {
        /* Format stimmt nicht falsches oder kein Trennzeichen
           no error haldling so far
           cut to 1 and zero by default */
        }
        else
        {
          AnzHalf = _strtod(_strmid(SeqPrepText,(Midpoint+1),(StrLaenge-Midpoint-1)));
        }
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Listings can only scan for tokens. You need more. So I think you need a more powerful tool to highlight such code. Maybe pygments. However therefor you have to write a new Lexer.

Comment: You say, it is not possible to highlight numbers within coments in comment color, while they are otherwise in red? i.e. is there no hierarchy in the colour scheme?

Comment: This looks like C with different keywords to me, so modifying the Pygments C lexer to create one for this language shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: @You: I thought the same but was not able to find any rules for the required language. Jonas: Sorry for this bad news. What do you mean with hierarchy?

Comment: I meant, that numbers within comments and strings should not get colored: 1. color all the numbers, 2. color all the comments and strings. -> the numbers in string/comments will not be red.

Comment: Blue keywords can be achieved adding `keywords=[1]{if,string,number,else},keywordstyle=[1]{\color{blue}}` in the Isodat language definition.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

I found it here:
[How can I change the color of digits when using the listings package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23634/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-digits-when-using-the-listings-package)

@Clément: Add a star before the zero, i.e. {0}{{{\color{red}0}}}1 -> *{0}{{{\color{red}0}}}1 to only colour outside of strings and comments. You only need to do this once, so not for the rest of the numerals. – Mark S. Everitt Jan 31 '12 at 15:57

Change

```
 {"}{{{\ProcessQuote{"}}}}1% Disable coloring within double quotes
 {0}{{\ColorIfNotInString{0}}}{1}%
```

to

```
 *{0}{{\ColorIfNotInString{0}}}{1}%
```

So it looks like:

[image: .png of .pdf from .tex.]

```
\documentclass[fleqn, a4paper, landscape]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{isored}{rgb}{0.6,0,0} % for strings
\definecolor{isogreen}{rgb}{0.25,0.6,0.2} % comments
\definecolor{isoblue}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,1} % keyword
\definecolor{isolightblue}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,1.0} % keywords
\definecolor{isocomgreen}{rgb}{0.25,0.35,0.75} % javadoc

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newtoggle{InString}{}% Keep track of if we are within a string
\togglefalse{InString}% Assume not initally in string
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34896/coloring-digits-with-the-listings-package?rq=1
\newcommand*{\ColorIfNotInString}[1]{\iftoggle{InString}{#1}{\textcolor{isored}#1}}%
\newcommand*{\ProcessQuote}[1]{#1\iftoggle{InString}{\global\togglefalse{InString}}{\global\toggletrue{InString}}}%

\usepackage{listings} 

\lstdefinelanguage{isodat}
{%
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,%
  literate=%
     *{0}{{\ColorIfNotInString{0}}}{1}%
     {1}{{\ColorIfNotInString{1}}}{1}%
     {2}{{\ColorIfNotInString{2}}}{1}%
     {3}{{\ColorIfNotInString{3}}}{1}%
     {4}{{\ColorIfNotInString{4}}}{1}%
     {5}{{\ColorIfNotInString{5}}}{1}%
     {6}{{\ColorIfNotInString{6}}}{1}%
     {7}{{\ColorIfNotInString{7}}}{1}%
     {8}{{\ColorIfNotInString{8}}}{1}%
     {9}{{\ColorIfNotInString{9}}}{1}%
     {.0}{{\ColorIfNotInString{.0}}}{1}% Following is to ensure that only periods
     {.1}{{\ColorIfNotInString{.1}}}{1}% followed by a digit are changed.
     {.2}{{\ColorIfNotInString{.2}}}{1}%
     {.3}{{\ColorIfNotInString{.3}}}{1}%
     {.4}{{\ColorIfNotInString{.4}}}{1}%
     {.5}{{\ColorIfNotInString{.5}}}{1}%
     {.6}{{\ColorIfNotInString{.6}}}{1}%
     {.7}{{\ColorIfNotInString{.7}}}{1}%
     {.8}{{\ColorIfNotInString{.8}}}{1}%
     {.9}{{\ColorIfNotInString{.9}}}{1}%
     {\ }{{ }}{1}% handle the space
     ,
     %string=[s]{_}{=},
     %string=[s]{_}{(}, 
  mathescape=true, 
  emphstyle={[2]\color{isoblue}},
  tabsize=4,
  captionpos=b,
  showstringspaces=false,
  keywordstyle=\color{isoblue},
  keywordstyle=[2]\color{isoblue},
  commentstyle=\color{isogreen},%
  stringstyle=\color{isolightblue},%
  morestring=[s][\color{isoblue}]{"}{"},%
  morecomment = [l]{//},
  morecomment = [l]{///},
  morecomment = [s]{/*}{*/},
  sensitive = true,
  morekeywords = {if, else, string, number},%You need to add here
  emph={_Set, _Delay, _strstr, _strtod, _strmid},% You need to add here
  emphstyle=\color{isolightblue},
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{lstlisting}[caption=Isodat language sample..,language=isodat]

        _Set("Precon/Trap 3",0);
        _Delay(1000,1,"Evacuating Carbon trap")
        //_Set("ExtValveBlock/Valve 4",1); commented because interferes with extraction

        string SeqPrepText="";
        number AnzFull=1;

        SeqPrepText =_GetSequenceText("Preparation","1,0");
        //_MessageBox(SeqPrepText,MB_OK,MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);        

        Midpoint    = _strstr (SeqPrepText,",");
        if (Midpoint==-1) 
        {
        /* Format stimmt nicht falsches oder kein Trennzeichen
           no error haldling so far
           cut to 1 and zero by default */
        }
        else
        {
          AnzHalf = _strtod(_strmid(SeqPrepText,(Midpoint+1),(StrLaenge-Midpoint-1)));
        }
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not able to fix the color of the number, can you check with the following code:

```
\lstdefinelanguage{isodat}
{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,%
  literate=%
  %         {"}{{{\ProcessQuote{"}}}}1% Disable coloring within double quotes
     {0}{{\ColorIfNotInString{0}}}{1}%
     {1}{{\ColorIfNotInString{1}}}{1}%
     {2}{{\ColorIfNotInString{2}}}{1}%
     {3}{{\ColorIfNotInString{3}}}{1}%
     {4}{{\ColorIfNotInString{4}}}{1}%
     {5}{{\ColorIfNotInString{5}}}{1}%
     {6}{{\ColorIfNotInString{6}}}{1}%
     {7}{{\ColorIfNotInString{7}}}{1}%
     {8}{{\ColorIfNotInString{8}}}{1}%
     {9}{{\ColorIfNotInString{9}}}{1}%
     {.0}{{\ColorIfNotInString{.0}}}{1}% Following is to ensure that only periods
     {.1}{{\ColorIfNotInString{.1}}}{1}% followed by a digit are changed.
     {.2}{{\ColorIfNotInString{.2}}}{1}%
     {.3}{{\ColorIfNotInString{.3}}}{1}%
     {.4}{{\ColorIfNotInString{.4}}}{1}%
     {.5}{{\ColorIfNotInString{.5}}}{1}%
     {.6}{{\ColorIfNotInString{.6}}}{1}%
     {.7}{{\ColorIfNotInString{.7}}}{1}%
     {.8}{{\ColorIfNotInString{.8}}}{1}%
     {.9}{{\ColorIfNotInString{.9}}}{1}%
     {\ }{{ }}{1}% handle the space
     ,
  mathescape=true, 
  emphstyle={[2]\color{isoblue}},
  tabsize=4,
  captionpos=b,
  showstringspaces=false,
  keywordstyle=\color{isoblue},
  keywordstyle=[2]\color{isoblue},
  commentstyle=\color{isogreen},%
  stringstyle=\color{isolightblue},%
  morestring=[s][\color{isoblue}]{"}{"},%
  morecomment = [l]{//}, 
  morecomment = [l]{///},
  morecomment = [s]{/*}{*/},
  sensitive = true,
  morekeywords = {if, else, string, number},%You need to add here
  emph={_Set, _Delay, _strstr, _strtod, _strmid},% You need to add here
  emphstyle=\color{isolightblue},
}
```

Comment: Nice one! I included your solution into the question, so that it gets easier to follow. But too bad you had to remove `string=[s]{_}{=},` and `string=[s]{_}{(},`. - Is there no way of setting like from (inclusive) to (exclusive)?