# Automatic line breaks of long numbers in listings

Tags: listings, line-breaking

How can I automatically break long numbers in a listing? Redefining \lst@lettertrue doesn't work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  breaklines=true
}
\makeatletter
\def\lst@lettertrue{\let\lst@ifletter\iffalse}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
  5646534535677654567453241456765467863576465467345675856382436457687534678665425769888843222222222587
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `literate` one-to-one replacement of all numerals (as reference, see [How can I format all numbers in `listings`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32174/5764)):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}% http://ctan.org/pkg/listings

\lstset{
    breaklines=true,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
  5646534535677654567453241456765467863576465467345675856382436457687534678665425769888843222222222587
\end{lstlisting}

\lstset{% Literate one-to-one mapping of numerals
    literate={0}{0}{1}%
             {1}{1}{1}%
             {2}{2}{1}%
             {3}{3}{1}%
             {4}{4}{1}%
             {5}{5}{1}%
             {6}{6}{1}%
             {7}{7}{1}%
             {8}{8}{1}%
             {9}{9}{1}%
}

\begin{lstlisting}
  5646534535677654567453241456765467863576465467345675856382436457687534678665425769888843222222222587
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Of course, this may break regular numerals that you don't want to break as well. However, I'm not sure whether this might be an issue.

Comment: Thx, this does the trick!