# Display issues drawing DNA sequences with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following TikZ code shows a representation of DNA code segments.

I have two different versions of this code. Version 1 uses multipart
rectangles, and is my preferred version. Version 2 models the DNA
sequences as individual squares stuck together. The issue with that is
that these squares tend to come unstuck on changing scale, which is
annoying.

Partly for that reason, I prefer version 1, but it has some problems.
If these can't be fixed, then I will use version 2.

Here is the problems.

1) The block on the left, call this block A, has the colors bleeding
outside the boxes in some places. Particularly on the right side. See
for example the bottom right corner, where the square flanked by
$X_{9}$ and $X^{(6)}$. Here this bleeding of the color out of the
square is quite noticeable. It can be seen in other places as
well. This effect becomes much less if

```
\tikzstyle{every path}=[very thick]
```

is removed. However, I want the thick paths. This might be the result
of user error, or a bug. I think it might be the cumulative result
of rounding errors as TikZ moves along calculating the dimensions of
the parts of the rectangle, since it gets worse as one moves to the
right. The question is whether there is a way around it.

2) The arrows from block A to the right should have an arrow head only
at the termination point, but has arrows on both ends.

3) The boxes on the left and the right should be aligned. They are
aligned on the top, but not the bottom.

Finally, a few questions which are not strictly problems.

4) Any suggestions to stop the arrows from obscuring the labels? Maybe
make the labels a different color? Is there an easy way to superimpose
the labels on top of the arrows?

5) Is there any way to make the division lines within the multipart
rectangles a different thickness from the other lines?

6) How can I make the block of code which begins with

```
\node [below] at (leftrow6.one south) {$\mathsmaller{\mathbf{X_{0}}}$};
```

into a loop? An attempt is below, namely

```
\foreach \i in {one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten}
{
  \foreach \j in {0,...,9}
  {
    \node [below] at (leftrow6.\i south) {$\mathsmaller{\mathbf{X_{\j}}}$};
  }
}
```

but this does not work.

The code for the two versions follow. Suggestions for improvement, including reducing lines of code appreciated. The image for version 1 is at the bottom.

Version 1

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows, positioning, calc, patterns, shadows, external}
%%%<
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%
%%%>
\usetikzlibrary{chains,fit,shapes, shapes.multipart}
\begin{document}
\changefontsizes{20pt}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{every path}=[very thick]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex', thick]

\tikzstyle{seq}=[rectangle split, rectangle split horizontal, rectangle split parts=#1, minimum height=1cm, draw, anchor=center]

\matrix[row sep=0.5cm] at (0cm, 4cm)
{
\node [seq=10, rectangle split part fill={blue!20, none, cyan!30, none, blue!20, none, none, cyan!30, none, cyan!30}] (leftrow1)
{C \nodepart{two} \phantom{X} \nodepart{three} A \nodepart{four} \phantom{X} \nodepart{five} G \nodepart{six} \phantom{X} \nodepart{seven} \phantom{X} \nodepart{eight} G \nodepart{nine} \phantom{X} \nodepart{ten} C}; \\

\node [seq=10, rectangle split part fill={green!20, none, orange!50, none, green!20, none, none, orange!50, none, orange!50}] (leftrow2)
{A \nodepart{two} \phantom{X} \nodepart{three} C \nodepart{four} \phantom{X} \nodepart{five} C \nodepart{six} \phantom{X} \nodepart{seven} \phantom{X} \nodepart{eight} A \nodepart{nine} \phantom{X} \nodepart{ten} A}; \\

\node [seq=10, rectangle split part fill={green!20, none, yellow!50, none, green!20, none, none, yellow!50, none, yellow!50}] (leftrow3)
{A \nodepart{two} \phantom{X} \nodepart{three} T \nodepart{four} \phantom{X} \nodepart{five} C \nodepart{six} \phantom{X} \nodepart{seven} \phantom{X} \nodepart{eight} T \nodepart{nine} \phantom{X} \nodepart{ten} T}; \\

\node [seq=10, rectangle split part fill={blue!20, none, cyan!30, none, blue!20, none, none, cyan!30, none, cyan!30}] (leftrow4)
{C \nodepart{two} \phantom{X} \nodepart{three} A \nodepart{four} \phantom{X} \nodepart{five} G \nodepart{six} \phantom{X} \nodepart{seven} \phantom{X} \nodepart{eight} G \nodepart{nine} \phantom{X} \nodepart{ten} C}; \\

\node [seq=10, rectangle split part fill={blue!20, none, cyan!30, none, blue!20, none, none, cyan!30, none, cyan!30}] (leftrow5)
{C \nodepart{two} \phantom{X} \nodepart{three} A \nodepart{four} \phantom{X} \nodepart{five} G \nodepart{six} \phantom{X} \nodepart{seven} \phantom{X} \nodepart{eight} G \nodepart{nine} \phantom{X} \nodepart{ten} C}; \\

\node [seq=10, rectangle split part fill={red!50, none, orange!50, none, red!50, none, none, orange!50, none, orange!50}] (leftrow6)
{A \nodepart{two} \phantom{X} \nodepart{three} C \nodepart{four} \phantom{X} \nodepart{five} A \nodepart{six} \phantom{X} \nodepart{seven} \phantom{X} \nodepart{eight} A \nodepart{nine} \phantom{X} \nodepart{ten} A}; \\
};

\node [below] at (leftrow6.one south) {$\mathsmaller{\mathbf{X_{0}}}$};
\node [below] at (leftrow6.two south) {$\mathsmaller{\mathbf{X_{1}}}$};
\node [below] at (leftrow6.three south) {$\mathsmaller{\mathbf{X_{2}}}$};
\node [below] at (leftrow6.four south) {$\mathsmaller{\mathbf{X_{3}}}$};
\node [below] at (leftrow6.five south) {$\mathsmaller{\mathbf{X_{4}}}$};
\node [below] at (leftrow6.six south) {$\mathsmaller{\mathbf{X_{5}}}$};
\node [below] at (leftrow6.seven south) {$\mathsmaller{\mathbf{X_{6}}}$};
\node [below] at (leftrow6.eight south) {$\mathsmaller{\mathbf{X_{7}}}$};
\node [below] at (leftrow6.nine south) {$\mathsmaller{\mathbf{X_{8}}}$};
\node [below] at (leftrow6.ten south) {$\mathsmaller{\mathbf{X_{9}}}$};

%loop version does not work
%\foreach \i in {{one}, {two}, {three}, {four}, {five}, {six}, {seven}, {eight},   
%{nine}, {ten}}
%{
%  \foreach \j in {0,...,9}
% {
%    \node [below] at (leftrow6.\i south) {$\mathsmaller{\mathbf{X_{\j}}}$};
% }
%}

% loop version does not work
\foreach \i in {1,...,6}
{
  \node [right] at (leftrow\i.ten east) {$\mathsmaller{\mathbf{X^{(\i)}}}$};
}

\matrix[row sep=0.5cm] at (10cm, 4cm)
{
\node [seq=2, rectangle split part fill={blue!20, blue!20}] (tupletoprow)
{C \nodepart{two} G}; \\
\node [seq=2, rectangle split part fill={green!20, green!20}]
{A \nodepart{two} C}; \\
\node [seq=2, rectangle split part fill={green!20, green!20}]
{A \nodepart{two} C}; \\
\node [seq=2, rectangle split part fill={blue!20, blue!20}]
{C \nodepart{two} G}; \\
\node [seq=2, rectangle split part fill={blue!20, blue!20}]
{C \nodepart{two} G}; \\
\node [seq=2, rectangle split part fill={red!50, red!50}] (tuplebottomrow)
{A \nodepart{two} A}; \\
};

\matrix[row sep=0.5cm] at (13cm, 4cm)
{
  \node [seq=3, rectangle split part fill={cyan!30, cyan!30}] (tripletoprow)
  {A \nodepart{two} G \nodepart{three} C}; \\
  \node [seq=3, rectangle split part fill={orange!50, orange!50}]
  {C \nodepart{two} A \nodepart{three} A}; \\
  \node [seq=3, rectangle split part fill={yellow!50, yellow!50}]
  {T \nodepart{two} T \nodepart{three} T}; \\
  \node [seq=3, rectangle split part fill={cyan!30, cyan!30}]
  {A \nodepart{two} G \nodepart{three} C}; \\
  \node [seq=3, rectangle split part fill={cyan!30, cyan!30}]
  {A \nodepart{two} G \nodepart{three} C}; \\
 \node [seq=3, rectangle split part fill={orange!50, orange!50}]  (triplebottomrow)
  {C \nodepart{two} A \nodepart{three} A}; \\
};

\node [below] at (tuplebottomrow.south) {$(\mathsmaller{\mathbf{X_{0}}}, \mathsmaller{\mathbf{X_{4}}})$};
\node [below] at (triplebottomrow.south) {$(\mathsmaller{\mathbf{X_{3}}}, \mathsmaller{\mathbf{X_{7}}}, , \mathsmaller{\mathbf{X_{9}}})$};

\node [above] at (tupletoprow.north) {(0, 4)};
\node [above] at (tripletoprow.north) {(3, 7, 9)};

\path [line] (leftrow6.one south) edge[out=270, in=270] node {}(tuplebottomrow);
\path [line] (leftrow6.five south) edge[out=270, in=270] node {}(tuplebottomrow);

\path [line] (leftrow1.three north) edge[out=90, in=90] node {}(tripletoprow);
\path [line] (leftrow1.eight north) edge[out=90, in=90] node {}(tripletoprow);
\path [line] (leftrow1.ten north) edge[out=90, in=90] node {}(tripletoprow);

\end{tikzpicture}
\changefontsizes{12pt}
\end{document}
```

Version 2

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows, positioning, calc, patterns, shadows, external}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%
\usetikzlibrary{chains,fit,shapes}

\begin{document}
\changefontsizes{15pt}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{every path}=[very thick]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex', thick]
\edef\sizeseqbox{1.3cm}
\tikzstyle{seq}=[draw,minimum size=\sizeseqbox]

\matrix [row sep=3mm] at (-7, 0)
{
  \node []{}; & \node []{}; & \node [] {}; & \node []{}; & \node []{}; & \node []{}; & \node []{}; & \node []{}; & \node []{}; & \node [] {}; \\
  \node [seq, fill=blue!20]{C}; & \node [seq]{}; & \node [seq, fill=cyan!30] (triplecol1left) {A}; & \node [seq]{}; & \node [seq, fill=blue!20]{G}; & \node [seq]{}; & \node [seq]{}; & \node [seq, fill=cyan!30] (triplecol2left) {G}; & \node [seq]{}; & \node [seq, fill=cyan!30] (triplecol3left) {C}; & \node [] {$\mathbf{X^{(1)}}$};\\
  \node [seq, fill=green!20]{A}; & \node [seq]{}; & \node [seq, fill=orange!50]{C}; & \node [seq]{}; & \node [seq, fill=green!20]{C}; & \node [seq]{}; & \node [seq]{}; & \node [seq, fill=orange!50]{A}; & \node [seq]{}; & \node [seq, fill=orange!50]{A}; & \node [] {$\mathbf{X^{(2)}}$};\\
  \node [seq, fill=green!20]{A}; & \node [seq]{}; & \node [seq, fill=yellow!50]{T}; & \node [seq]{}; & \node [seq, fill=green!20]{C}; & \node [seq]{}; & \node [seq]{}; & \node [seq, fill=yellow!50]{T}; & \node [seq]{}; & \node [seq, fill=yellow!50]{T}; & \node [] {$\mathbf{X^{(3)}}$};\\
  \node [seq, fill=blue!20]{C}; & \node [seq]{}; & \node [seq, fill=cyan!30]{A}; & \node [seq]{}; & \node [seq, fill=blue!20]{G}; & \node [seq]{}; & \node [seq]{}; & \node [seq, fill=cyan!30]{G}; & \node [seq]{}; & \node [seq, fill=cyan!30]{C}; & \node [] {$\mathbf{X^{(4)}}$};\\
  \node [seq, fill=blue!20]{C}; & \node [seq]{}; & \node [seq, fill=cyan!30]{A}; & \node [seq]{}; & \node [seq, fill=blue!20]{G}; & \node [seq]{}; & \node [seq]{}; & \node [seq, fill=cyan!30]{G}; & \node [seq]{}; & \node [seq, fill=cyan!30]{C}; & \node [] {$\mathbf{X^{(5)}}$};\\
  \node [seq, fill=red!50] (tuplecol1left) {A}; & \node [seq]{}; & \node [seq, fill=orange!50] {C}; & \node [seq]{}; & \node [seq, fill=red!50] (tuplecol2left)  {A}; & \node [seq]{}; & \node [seq]{}; & \node [seq, fill=orange!50] {A}; & \node [seq]{}; & \node [seq, fill=orange!50] {A}; & \node [] {$\mathbf{X^{(6)}}$};\\
  \node []{$\mathbf{X_{0}}$}; & \node []{$\mathbf{X_{1}}$}; & \node [] {$\mathbf{X_{2}}$}; & \node []{$\mathbf{X_{3}}$}; & \node []{$\mathbf{X_{4}}$}; & \node []{$\mathbf{X_{5}}$}; & \node []{$\mathbf{X_{6}}$}; & \node []{$\mathbf{X_{7}}$}; & \node []{$\mathbf{X_{8}}$}; & \node [] {$\mathbf{X_{9}}$}; \\
};

\matrix [row sep=3mm] at (5, 0)
{
 \node [] {(0,}; & \node [] {4)}; \\
  \node [seq, fill=blue!20]{C}; & \node [seq, fill=blue!20]{G}; \\
  \node [seq, fill=green!20]{A}; & \node [seq, fill=green!20]{C}; \\
  \node [seq, fill=green!20]{A}; & \node [seq, fill=green!20]{C}; \\
  \node [seq, fill=blue!20]{C}; & \node [seq, fill=blue!20]{G}; \\
  \node [seq, fill=blue!20]{C}; & \node [seq, fill=blue!20]{G}; \\
  \node [seq, fill=red!50] (tuplecol1right) {A}; & \node [seq, fill=red!50] (tuplecol2right) {A}; \\
  \node [] {$(\mathbf{X_0},$}; & \node [] {$\mathbf{X_4})$}; \\
};

\matrix [row sep=3mm] at (9, 0)
{
  \node [] {(2,};                 & \node [] {7,};                   & \node [] {9)};                   \\
  \node [seq, fill=cyan!30] (triplecol1right) {A}; & \node [seq, fill=cyan!30]  (triplecol2right) {G}; & \node [seq, fill=cyan!30] (triplecol3right) {C}; \\
  \node [seq, fill=orange!50]{C}; & \node [seq, fill=orange!50]{A}; & \node [seq, fill=orange!50]{A}; \\
  \node [seq, fill=yellow!50]{T}; & \node [seq, fill=yellow!50]{T}; & \node [seq, fill=yellow!50]{T}; \\
  \node [seq, fill=cyan!30]{A};   & \node [seq, fill=cyan!30]{G};   & \node [seq, fill=cyan!30]{C};   \\
  \node [seq, fill=cyan!30]{A};   & \node [seq, fill=cyan!30]{G};   & \node [seq, fill=cyan!30]{C};   \\
  \node [seq, fill=orange!50] {C};& \node [seq, fill=orange!50] {A};& \node [seq, fill=orange!50] {A};\\
  \node [] {($\mathbf{X_2},$};                   & \node [] {$\mathbf{X_7},$};                   & \node [] {$\mathbf{X_9})$};                   \\
};

\path [line] (tuplecol1left) edge[out=270, in=270] node {}(tuplecol1right.south east);
\path [line] (tuplecol2left) edge[out=270, in=270] node {}(tuplecol2right.south west);

\path [line] (triplecol1left) edge[out=90, in=90] node {}(triplecol2right);
\path [line] (triplecol2left) edge[out=90, in=90] node {}(triplecol2right);
\path [line] (triplecol3left) edge[out=90, in=90] node {}(triplecol2right);

\end{tikzpicture}
\changefontsizes{12pt}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There seems to several unrelated questions here: color bleed outside of multi part rectangles, arrow heads on both ends and shorter arrows, alignment of boxes, different division lines of multipart rectangles, looping construct. I would suggest you compose separate questions on these specific items as then those questions/answers will be helpful to others, and also be easier to find.

Comment: I would have done this in a totally different way using `listings` for [typesetting different characters with different colors in a DNA sequence](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16572/typesetting-different-characters-with-different-colors-in-a-dna-sequence) and, or similar processing in `tikz` to add coloring and boxes, with automatic insertion of `\tikzmark` at each node. Then do the arrow drawgins based on the `\tikzmark`s.

Comment: @PeterGrill: I guess you might be right about the multiple questions thing. I suppose I was lazy. I'd be interested in a different approach to this, if you feel like providing details.

Comment: [Change fontsize inside float in KOMA class](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/223584)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1) and 3) Change `none` to `white` when filling the parts of the rectangles.

2) Change the stile for the line to have arrow tip only on one end (I wasn't sure which ones to you wanted to change, so I chose the two on the bottom).

4) One possibility is to draw the arrows first, and then place the labels (shifting them a little bit vertically, if required).

6) Loops fixed.

Additionally, I changed from the old `\tikzstyle` syntax to the newer `\tikzset`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows, positioning, calc, patterns, shadows, external}
%%%<
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%
%%%>
\usetikzlibrary{chains,fit,shapes, shapes.multipart}

\begin{document}
\changefontsizes{20pt}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
  every path/.style={very thick},
  line/.style={draw, -latex', thick},
  seq/.style={rectangle split,
    rectangle split horizontal,
    rectangle split parts=#1,
    minimum height=1cm,
    draw, anchor=center}
}

\matrix[row sep=0.5cm] at (0cm, 4cm)
{
\node [seq=10, rectangle split part fill={blue!20,white, cyan!30,white, blue!20, white, white, cyan!30,white,cyan!30}] (leftrow1)
{C \nodepart{two} \phantom{X} \nodepart{three} A \nodepart{four} \phantom{X} \nodepart{five} G \nodepart{six} \phantom{X} \nodepart{seven} \phantom{X} \nodepart{eight} G \nodepart{nine} \phantom{X} \nodepart{ten} C}; \\

\node [seq=10, rectangle split part fill={green!20, white, orange!50, white, green!20, white, white, orange!50, white, orange!50}] (leftrow2)
{A \nodepart{two} \phantom{X} \nodepart{three} C \nodepart{four} \phantom{X} \nodepart{five} C \nodepart{six} \phantom{X} \nodepart{seven} \phantom{X} \nodepart{eight} A \nodepart{nine} \phantom{X} \nodepart{ten} A}; \\

\node [seq=10, rectangle split part fill={green!20, white, yellow!50, white, green!20, white, white, yellow!50, white, yellow!50}] (leftrow3)
{A \nodepart{two} \phantom{X} \nodepart{three} T \nodepart{four} \phantom{X} \nodepart{five} C \nodepart{six} \phantom{X} \nodepart{seven} \phantom{X} \nodepart{eight} T \nodepart{nine} \phantom{X} \nodepart{ten} T}; \\

\node [seq=10, rectangle split part fill={blue!20, white, cyan!30, white, blue!20, white, white, cyan!30, white, cyan!30}] (leftrow4)
{C \nodepart{two} \phantom{X} \nodepart{three} A \nodepart{four} \phantom{X} \nodepart{five} G \nodepart{six} \phantom{X} \nodepart{seven} \phantom{X} \nodepart{eight} G \nodepart{nine} \phantom{X} \nodepart{ten} C}; \\

\node [seq=10, rectangle split part fill={blue!20, white, cyan!30, white, blue!20, white, white, cyan!30, white, cyan!30}] (leftrow5)
{C \nodepart{two} \phantom{X} \nodepart{three} A \nodepart{four} \phantom{X} \nodepart{five} G \nodepart{six} \phantom{X} \nodepart{seven} \phantom{X} \nodepart{eight} G \nodepart{nine} \phantom{X} \nodepart{ten} C}; \\

\node [seq=10, rectangle split part fill={red!50, white, orange!50, white, red!50, white, white, orange!50, white, orange!50}] (leftrow6)
{A \nodepart{two} \phantom{X} \nodepart{three} C \nodepart{four} \phantom{X} \nodepart{five} A \nodepart{six} \phantom{X} \nodepart{seven} \phantom{X} \nodepart{eight} A \nodepart{nine} \phantom{X} \nodepart{ten} A}; \\
};

\matrix[row sep=0.5cm] at (10cm, 4cm)
{
\node [seq=2, rectangle split part fill={blue!20, blue!20}] (tupletoprow)
{C \nodepart{two} G}; \\
\node [seq=2, rectangle split part fill={green!20, green!20}]
{A \nodepart{two} C}; \\
\node [seq=2, rectangle split part fill={green!20, green!20}]
{A \nodepart{two} C}; \\
\node [seq=2, rectangle split part fill={blue!20, blue!20}]
{C \nodepart{two} G}; \\
\node [seq=2, rectangle split part fill={blue!20, blue!20}]
{C \nodepart{two} G}; \\
\node [seq=2, rectangle split part fill={red!50, red!50}] (tuplebottomrow)
{A \nodepart{two} A}; \\
};

\matrix[row sep=0.5cm] at (13cm, 4cm)
{
  \node [seq=3, rectangle split part fill={cyan!30, cyan!30}] (tripletoprow)
  {A \nodepart{two} G \nodepart{three} C}; \\
  \node [seq=3, rectangle split part fill={orange!50, orange!50}]
  {C \nodepart{two} A \nodepart{three} A}; \\
  \node [seq=3, rectangle split part fill={yellow!50, yellow!50}]
  {T \nodepart{two} T \nodepart{three} T}; \\
  \node [seq=3, rectangle split part fill={cyan!30, cyan!30}]
  {A \nodepart{two} G \nodepart{three} C}; \\
  \node [seq=3, rectangle split part fill={cyan!30, cyan!30}]
  {A \nodepart{two} G \nodepart{three} C}; \\
  \node [seq=3, rectangle split part fill={orange!50, orange!50}]  (triplebottomrow)
  {C \nodepart{two} A \nodepart{three} A}; \\
};

\path [latex'-, thick] (leftrow6.one south) edge[out=270, in=270] node {}(tuplebottomrow);
\path [latex'-, thick] (leftrow6.five south) edge[out=270, in=270] node {}(tuplebottomrow);

\path [line] (leftrow1.three north) edge[out=90, in=90] node {}(tripletoprow);
\path [line] (leftrow1.eight north) edge[out=90, in=90] node {}(tripletoprow);
\path [line] (leftrow1.ten north) edge[out=90, in=90] node {}(tripletoprow);

%loop version works
\foreach \i [count=\x] in {one ,two ,three ,four ,five ,six ,seven ,eight ,nine ,ten }
    \node [below=8pt,fill=white] at (leftrow6.\i south) {$\mathsmaller{\mathbf{X_{\x}}}$};

% loop version works
\foreach \i in {1,...,6}
{
  \node [right] at (leftrow\i.ten east) {$\mathsmaller{\mathbf{X^{(\i)}}}$};
}

\node [below=8pt,fill=white] at (tuplebottomrow.south) {$(\mathsmaller{\mathbf{X_{0}}}, \mathsmaller{\mathbf{X_{4}}})$};
\node [below=8pt,fill=white] at (triplebottomrow.south) {$(\mathsmaller{\mathbf{X_{3}}}, \mathsmaller{\mathbf{X_{7}}}, , \mathsmaller{\mathbf{X_{9}}})$};

\node [above=8pt] at (tupletoprow.north) {(0, 4)};
\node [above=8pt,fill=white] at (tripletoprow.north) {(3, 7, 9)};

\end{tikzpicture}
\changefontsizes{12pt}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Gonzalo. Thanks for the answer. It will take me some time to digest. For (1), what did you need to change? Is this not a bug then? An explanation would be appreciated, so I can avoid the issue another time. I meant the arrows to go the other way. The solution for (4) looks good. Can you point me to a reference in the manual for the `\foreach \i [count=\x]` syntax used for (6) (the loop)?

Comment: @FaheemMitha You're welcome! For (1), you had `none` as a color to fill the empty parts; however, `none` is not a color, so you can use `white` instead. You can easily change the direction of the arrows (if not, please let me know exactly which arrows should be changed and I'll explain how to do it).

Comment: I think your numbering is a bit off, which confused me. I think (1) and (2) should just be (1) (bleeding issue). Also (3) should be (2) (arrow issue). Are you saying the `none` caused the problem with the bleeding? Also, curious how you fixed (3) (the alignment issue). Thanks for the impressive help. Let me review and maybe I'll be back with more questions.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Yes, `none` solved the bleeding and alignment issues.

Comment: Oh, maybe you meant to write (1) and (3) and then (2) on the next line?

Comment: @FaheemMitha you're right; I didn't noticed it. I did the change; thanks.

Comment: One thing I don't understand is, wrt 2 (the double headed arrows issue) you explicitly have `latex'-` in (for example) `\path [latex'-, thick] (leftrow6.one south) edge[out=270, in=270] node {}(tuplebottomrow);` In my example, I use just `\path[line]...` where `line` is defined with `\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex', thick]`. I don't understand why one worked and not the other.

Comment: I think using the `shorten` option to the arrow path is a better choice to stop the arrows obscuring the labels that writing the labels over the arrows. I didn't think such an option existed, so didn't look for it. :-)

Answer (score 18):

Not sure if this addresses any of your *specific* questions, as there are many disjoint ones in the posting. It would be better to split them into separate questions so that they might be of more help to others, and also easier to answer.  So this is more of a how I would recommend you do this kind of diagram.

Fist thing to figure out is *not* the diagram itself, but rather

> What is the actual information that you want to specify to obtain the desired result?

### 1. Capture the Data:

Since I am *not* knowledgeable in  DNA sequencing, there may well be a better way that more accurately reflects what you want, but the way I see it is that in each row you have three sets of DNA sequences. In a chat discussion you mentioned that there was not an easy algorithm to automatically determine the color to use, so the natural syntax I see is something such as:

```
\ThreeDNASequences
    {C/cyan,, A/orange,,,G/blue,,G/red!25,,C/yellow}
    {C/violet,G/brown}
    {A/cyan,G/yellow,C/brown};
```

where each of the three parameters represent the left, middle, and right sequence along with the color. Multiple subsequent commas are used to denote an empty cell.  So you would need one of these calls for each row of your diagram. So with three instances you get three rows:

[image]

### 2. Draw the Arrows:

The other portion of the problem is how to draw the arrows between the various nodes. Using a process similar to the `\tikzmark` we simply name each of the nodes using a counter to provide a unique reference to each column, and provide an optional parameter to the `\ThreeDNASequences` macro so that we can have a prefix to distinguish between the rows.

So using `\ThreeDNASequences[Top]{}{}{}` for the top row, and `\ThreeDNASequences[Bottom]{}{}{}` for the bottom row can be used to label the nodes as `Top-0`, `Top-1`, ..., and `Bottom-0`, `Bottom-1`, ... with which we can access each of those nodes. Since this also has a pattern where one node connects to many nodes, it makes sense to define a macro such as:

```
\ConnectNodes[red, out=100, in=80]
    {Top-12.north}
    {Top-2.north,Top-7.north,Top-9.north};
```

to specify the options of the lines, and the nodes to connect.

Putting these together you have:

[image]

### Further Enhancements:

- Since it is now possible to access each of the nodes, these nodes can be used to place the text that goes adjacent (below, right, or top) of each of these nodes.  Note that in the MWE below I did not provide a unique label to use for the middle rows as I was not concerned about the text that needs to be placed. So when placing the text it would be recommended that you also provide unique prefix for each row's node labels.
- One may need to tweak the arrows via `shorten` syntax if desired.
- The `xshift` used in `\ThreeDNASequences` should really be computed based on the number of members of the previous sequence.  This is really only important if the numbers of each of the columns might change in a different diagram.  I used `\pgfmathsetmacro{\Shift}{}` only to provide a place holder as to where this change may be needed.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, arrows}

\newcommand*{\NodeSize}{0.5cm}%
\newcommand*{\YShiftBetweenRows}{-1cm}% Subsequent rows are shited down so they don't overlap
\tikzset{DNA Style/.style={minimum size=0.5cm, draw=gray, line width=1pt}}{}

\newlength{\YShift}% 
\newcounter{ColumnCounter}% Prefix for node labels

% Initialize - These are probably not needed, but prefer to set them
\setlength{\YShift}{0cm}% 
\setcounter{ColumnCounter}{0}


\newcommand*{\DNASequence}[2][Mark]{%
    % http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12091/tikz-foreach-loop-with-macro-defined-list
    \def\Sequence{#2}
    \foreach [count=\xi] \Label/\Color in \Sequence {%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\XShift}{\NodeSize*\xi}%
        \IfStrEq{\Color}{}{\def\Color{white}}{}
        \edef\NodeName{#1-\arabic{ColumnCounter}}
        \node [DNA Style, fill=\Color, xshift=\XShift] (\NodeName) {\Label};
        \stepcounter{ColumnCounter}
    } 
}%


\newcommand*{\ThreeDNASequences}[4][Mark]{% #1 = tikzmark prefix
    \setcounter{ColumnCounter}{0}% reset column counter
    \begin{scope}[yshift=\YShift]
        \DNASequence[#1]{#2} 
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\Shift}{6cm}% Should compute this based on num of items in #1
        \begin{scope}[xshift=\Shift]
            \DNASequence[#1]{#3} 
        \end{scope}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\Shift}{8cm}% Should compute this based on num of items in #2  
        \begin{scope}[xshift=\Shift]
            \DNASequence[#1]{#4} 
        \end{scope}
    \end{scope}
    \pgfmathsetlength{\YShift}{\YShift\YShiftBetweenRows}%
}

\newcommand*{\ConnectNodes}[3][]{%
    % #1 = draw options
    % #2 = ending node
    % #3 = list of starting nodes
    \def\ListOfEndNodes{#3}
    \foreach \EndNode in \ListOfEndNodes {%
    \draw[latex'-, thick, #1] (#2) to[#1] (\EndNode);
    }%
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \ThreeDNASequences[Top]
        {C/blue!20,, A/cyan!30,,, G/blue!20,, G/cyan!30,, C/cyan!30}
        {C/blue!20, G/blue!20}
        {A/cyan!30, G/cyan!30, C/cyan!30};

    \ThreeDNASequences
        {A/green!20,, C/orange!50,,, C/green!20,, A/orange!50,, A/orange!50}
        {A/green!20, C/green!20}
        {C/orange!50, A/orange!50, A/orange!50};

    \ThreeDNASequences[Bottom]
        {C/blue!20,, A/cyan!30,,, G/blue!20,, G/cyan!30,, C/cyan!30}
        {C/blue!20, G/blue!20}
        {A/cyan!30, G/cyan!30, C/cyan!30};    

    % Now, draw the arrows as desired

\ConnectNodes[out=90, in=90]
        {Top-10.north east}
        {Top-0.north,Top-5.north};

    \ConnectNodes[out=-90, in=-90]
        {Bottom-13.south}
        {Bottom-2.south,Bottom-7.south,Bottom-9.south};  

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

I looked at the image a bit more and perhaps this is a slightly different way to show the merging of the cells:

[image]

It looks better with just one side showing, but the MWE below has the code (commented though) for the top as well:

### Code:

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fit,backgrounds}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background layer} 
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground layer} 
\pgfsetlayers{background layer,main,foreground layer}

\newcommand*{\NodeSize}{0.5cm}%
\newcommand*{\YShiftBetweenRows}{-1cm}% Subsequent rows are shited down so they don't overlap
\tikzset{DNA Style/.style={minimum size=0.5cm, draw=gray, line width=1pt}}

\tikzset{Fit Line Style 1/.style={draw=olive, thick, dotted}}
\tikzset{Fill Style 1/.style={fill=olive!20}}

\tikzset{Fit Line Style 2/.style={draw=green!50!black, thick, dashed}}
\tikzset{Fill Style 2/.style={fill=green!20}}

\newlength{\YShift}% 
\newcounter{ColumnCounter}% Prefix for node labels

% Initialize - These are probably not needed, but prefer to set them
\setlength{\YShift}{0cm}% 
\setcounter{ColumnCounter}{0}


\newcommand*{\DNASequence}[2][Mark]{%
    % http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12091/tikz-foreach-loop-with-macro-defined-list
    \def\Sequence{#2}
    \foreach [count=\xi] \Label/\Color in \Sequence {%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\XShift}{\NodeSize*\xi}%
        \IfStrEq{\Color}{}{\def\Color{white}}{}
        \edef\NodeName{#1-\arabic{ColumnCounter}}
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground layer}
        \node [DNA Style, fill=\Color, xshift=\XShift] (\NodeName) {\Label};
        \end{pgfonlayer}
        \stepcounter{ColumnCounter}
    } 
}%


\newcommand*{\ThreeDNASequences}[4][Mark]{% #1 = tikzmark prefix
    \setcounter{ColumnCounter}{0}% reset column counter
    \begin{scope}[yshift=\YShift]
        \DNASequence[#1]{#2} 
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\Shift}{6cm}% Should compute this based on num of items in #1
        \begin{scope}[xshift=\Shift]
            \DNASequence[#1]{#3} 
        \end{scope}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\Shift}{8cm}% Should compute this based on num of items in #2  
        \begin{scope}[xshift=\Shift]
            \DNASequence[#1]{#4} 
        \end{scope}
    \end{scope}
    \pgfmathsetlength{\YShift}{\YShift\YShiftBetweenRows}%
}

\newcommand*{\ConnectNodes}[3][]{%
    % #1 = draw options
    % #2 = ending node
    % #3 = list of starting nodes
    \def\ListOfEndNodes{#3}
    \foreach \EndNode in \ListOfEndNodes {%
    \draw[red, <->, thick, #1] (#2) to[#1] (\EndNode);
    }%
}

\newcommand*{\Fit}[3][]{\node [inner sep=2pt, #1, fit= #3] (#2) {};}%

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \ThreeDNASequences[Top]
        {C/blue!20,, A/cyan!30,,, G/blue!20,, G/cyan!30,, C/cyan!30}
        {C/blue!20, G/blue!20}
        {A/cyan!30, G/cyan!30, C/cyan!30};

    \ThreeDNASequences
        {A/green!20,, C/orange!50,,, C/green!20,, A/orange!50,, A/orange!50}
        {A/green!20, C/green!20}
        {C/orange!50, A/orange!50, A/orange!50};

    \ThreeDNASequences[Bottom]
        {C/blue!20,, A/cyan!30,,, G/blue!20,, G/cyan!30,, C/cyan!30}
        {C/blue!20, G/blue!20}
        {A/cyan!30, G/cyan!30, C/cyan!30};

%    % Now, draw the arrows as desired
%
%   \ConnectNodes[red, out=100, in=80, ]
%       {Top-12.north}
%       {Top-2.north,Top-7.north,Top-9.north};
%
%   \ConnectNodes[blue, out=-80, in=-100]
%       {Bottom-10.south east}
%       {Bottom-2.south,Bottom-7.south,Bottom-9.south};


   % Bottom connections
    \Fit[Fit Line Style 1, Fill Style 1]{LeftB1}{(Top-0.north west) (Bottom-0.south east)}
    \Fit[Fit Line Style 1, Fill Style 1]{LeftB2}{(Top-5.north west) (Bottom-5.south east)}
    \Fit[Fit Line Style 1, Fill Style 1]{RightB1}{(Top-10.north west) (Bottom-11.south east)}


    \ConnectNodes[Fit Line Style 1, solid, <-, out=-120, in=-20]
        {RightB1.south}
        {LeftB1.south, LeftB2.south};

%   % Top connections
%   \Fit[Fit Line Style 2, Fill Style 2]{LeftT1}{(Top-2.north west) (Bottom-2.south east)}
%   \Fit[Fit Line Style 2, Fill Style 2]{LeftT2}{(Top-7.north west) (Bottom-7.south east)}
%   \Fit[Fit Line Style 2, Fill Style 2]{LeftT3}{(Top-9.north west) (Bottom-9.south east)}
%   \Fit[Fit Line Style 2, Fill Style 2]{RightT1}{(Top-12.north west) (Bottom-14.south east)}
%
%
%   \ConnectNodes[Fit Line Style 2, solid, out=100, in=80, <-]
%       {RightT1.north}
%       {LeftT1.north, LeftT2.north, LeftT3.north};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```