# Double unwanted arrow tip in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I'm trying to make an arrow with a round tip. The arrow comes exactly as I want it except that it gets a double tip, while I want only one. I checked the code multiple times but without success, maybe it's a default option?

Here is the picture of the section (ignore the style, it's very spartan since it's a minimal code):

[image: double arrow tip]

And here is the code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,backgrounds,snakes}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

    \tikzset{
proar/.style={
    draw=black,
    -*,
    fill=green,
    }}

     \begin{tikzpicture}[y=-6.6mm]
                \centering

        \filldraw[fill=white, midway, draw, inner sep=1pt] (8.2,-1) rectangle (8.8,5.5);

        \foreach \y [evaluate=\y as \year using int(1700+\y*10)] in {0,1,...,5}{ 

                \draw[] (8.5,\y) -- (8.5,\y) node[font=\scriptsize] {$\year$}; 
                \draw[] (8,\y) -- (8.2,\y);
                \draw[] (8.1,\y+.5) -- (8.2,\y+.5);
                \draw[] (8.8,\y) -- (9,\y);
                \draw[] (8.8,\y+.5) -- (8.9,\y+.5);
                }

        \draw[proar] (8.8,3) edge[out=0,in=180] (10,5) node[right] at (10,5) {random text};

        \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you add the `-*` option to the edge, instead of the draw, then you only get it on one side:

```
\draw[draw=black,fill=green] (8.8,3) edge[out=0,in=180,-*] (10,5) node[right] at (10,5) {random text};
```

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,backgrounds,snakes}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

    \tikzset{
proar/.style={
    draw=black,
    -*,
    fill=green,
    }}
     \begin{tikzpicture}[y=-6.6mm]
                \centering

        \filldraw[fill=white, midway, draw, inner sep=1pt] (8.2,-1) rectangle (8.8,5.5);

        \foreach \y [evaluate=\y as \year using int(1700+\y*10)] in {0,1,...,5}{ 

                \draw[] (8.5,\y) -- (8.5,\y) node[font=\scriptsize] {$\year$}; 
                \draw[] (8,\y) -- (8.2,\y);
                \draw[] (8.1,\y+.5) -- (8.2,\y+.5);
                \draw[] (8.8,\y) -- (9,\y);
                \draw[] (8.8,\y+.5) -- (8.9,\y+.5);
                }

        \draw[draw=black,fill=green] (8.8,3) edge[out=0,in=180,-*] (10,5) node[right] at (10,5) {random text};

        \end{tikzpicture}
     \begin{tikzpicture}[y=-6.6mm]
                \centering

        \filldraw[fill=white, midway, draw, inner sep=1pt] (8.2,-1) rectangle (8.8,5.5);

        \foreach \y [evaluate=\y as \year using int(1700+\y*10)] in {0,1,...,5}{ 

                \draw[] (8.5,\y) -- (8.5,\y) node[font=\scriptsize] {$\year$}; 
                \draw[] (8,\y) -- (8.2,\y);
                \draw[] (8.1,\y+.5) -- (8.2,\y+.5);
                \draw[] (8.8,\y) -- (9,\y);
                \draw[] (8.8,\y+.5) -- (8.9,\y+.5);
                }

        \draw[draw=black,fill=green] (8.8,3) edge[out=0,in=180,*-] (10,5) node[right] at (10,5) {random text};

        \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. So it *is* a default option?

Comment: @Alenanno I guess this is slightly related http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82326/odd-behaviour-with-arrows-and-multipart-rectangles