# Sinuous arrow between nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a sinuous arrow between two nodes. Following the first answer in this thread [Easy curves in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33607/easy-curves-in-tikz) I have tried the following code, but the arrow head points to the opposite side... how could I solve it? Thanks!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (A) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[scale=.1]{images/presentation/2/cell.png}};
    \node (B) at (8,-1) {\includegraphics[scale=.1]{images/presentation/2/cell2.png}};
    \draw[->, >=latex, blue, line width=6pt] (A.east) to (B.west);
    \draw [->, cyan, line width=3pt] plot [smooth, tension=1] coordinates{ ([yshift=.5cm]A.east) (2,2.5) (4,2) (6,3) ([yshift=.5cm]B.west)}; %this arrow head should point to the other side

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It looks like TikZ doesn’t know the incoming direction and calculates `atan(0/?) = 90°` (a typical sign that something went wrong). I fear that arrows do not work with `plot` out of the box … Using Jake’s answer and the `absolute supports` key, TikZ places the arrow tip correctly. By the way, we do not have these images. We’ll use `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the same problem with the `to` paths in [Odd behaviour with arrows and multipart rectangles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82326/odd-behaviour-with-arrows-and-multipart-rectangles)
so a tiny nudge is required for TikZ to restore the path direction.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{mwe}%<-- For dummy images
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (A) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[scale=.1]{example-image-a}};
    \node (B) at (8,-1) {\includegraphics[scale=.1]{example-image-b}};
    \draw[->, >=latex, blue, line width=6pt] (A.east) to (B.west);
    \draw [->,cyan, line width=3pt] 
               plot [smooth, tension=1] coordinates{%
                                                    ([yshift=.5cm]A.east)
                                                    (2,2.5)
                                                    (4,2)
                                                    (6,3)
                                                    ([yshift=5mm+5pt]B.west)}
                                                    --([yshift=5mm]B.west);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! It work perfectly!! sorry for the missing images, it was just to stress that there were actually images there, but any image would have been ok, like in your example. Thanks again!