# TikZ-picture: remove arrows at starting point of edge

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I'm a litte confused, because I drew a TikZ-picture and didn't get what I expected. Have look at the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, ngerman}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=0.8cm,y=0.8cm]
\draw[->,color=black] (-3.17,0) -- (5.5,0);
\foreach \x in {-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4,5}
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below] {\footnotesize $\x$};
\draw[->,color=black] (0,-3.22) -- (0,7.5); \foreach \y in {-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
\draw[shift={(0,\y)},color=black] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt) node[left] {\footnotesize $\y$};
\draw[color=black] (0pt,-10pt) node[right] {\footnotesize $0$};
\clip(-3.17,-3.22) rectangle (5.35,7.26);
\draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\draw (-1,0) rectangle (0,1);
\draw (0,-1) rectangle (1,-2);
\draw (3,0) rectangle (4,1);
\draw (0,4) rectangle (1,5);
\draw[->] (1,1) edge [bend right] node[above right] {$d_{A,P_1}$} (-1,1);
\draw[->] (-1,0) edge [bend right] node[left] {$d_{A,P_2}$} (0,-2);
\draw[->] (1,-2) edge [bend right] node[below right] {$d_{A,P_3}$} (4,0);
\draw[->] (4,1) edge [bend right] node[above right] {$d_{A,P_4}$} (1,5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I drew some bended edges, but the little arrows showing up at the starting point of my edge are not intended. I have no idea how to fix it but it has something to do with "edge".

Perhaps someone can help me out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you tell me the coordinates at which you do not wish to have the arrows?

Comment: Yes: (1,1), (-1,0),(1,-2),(4.1), the starting points of my edges

Comment: I found it: just replace "edge" by "to". I don't know why, but it worked

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82326/odd-behaviour-with-arrows-and-multipart-rectangles has some explanation of why this occurs. If you agree we can close as duplicate. Note that, as percusse mentions in his answer to the above question, you could also move the arrow specification to the `edge` itself, i.e. `\draw (0,0) edge[->] ...`

Comment: You're allowed to close as duplicated