# Arrow from brace to node

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-arrows, pgf-decorations

I would like to draw an arrow from the tip of a curly bracket to a node, but if I do the following, an extra arrow point is drawn just above the tip of the brace.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (A) at (0,0) {Hello};
  \draw[decorate, decoration={brace, amplitude=10pt}] (2.2,-1.8) -- coordinate [left=10pt] (B) (2.2,-0.3) node {};
  \draw[-latex] (B) edge (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It looks very strange and I have no idea how this extra arrow got there. If I switch the B and the A like `\draw[-latex] (A) edge (B);`, only one arrow is drawn, can anybody explain this and explain how to do the above correctly?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Almost duplicate http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82326/odd-behaviour-with-arrows-and-multipart-rectangles. Edges should admit their own options.

Comment: See also [http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15587/43317](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15587/43317)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem involves the use of `edge` which creates a second construction *after* the main path is drawn. Since `[-latex]` applies to the entire command until the `;`, you end up with 2 arrows. Replacing `edge` with a regular `--` removes the problem:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (A) at (0,0) {Hello};
  \draw[decorate, decoration={brace, amplitude=10pt}] (2.2,-1.8) -- coordinate [left=10pt] (B) (2.2,-0.3) node {};
  \draw[-latex] (B) -- (A);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Single arrow]