# tikz, modify code for drawing DNA sequence

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to modify how to draw [DNA sequences](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82230/11860).
There is a function `\DNASequence` which does the job.
It uses nodes of constant size. However, I need to put **arbitrary** text instead of only one letter in a cell. How to do it?
I tried to modify original code but I don't know how to get the actual width of a node.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Language = Spanish
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetheme{Warsaw} 
\usecolortheme{whale}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, arrows}

\newcommand*{\NodeSize}{0.5cm}%
\newcommand*{\YShiftBetweenRows}{-1cm}% Subsequent rows are shited down so they don't overlap
\tikzset{DNA Style/.style={minimum size=0.5cm, draw=gray, line width=1pt}}{}

\newlength{\YShift}% 
\newcounter{ColumnCounter}% Prefix for node labels

\setlength{\YShift}{0cm}% 
\setcounter{ColumnCounter}{0}
\newcounter{angle}
\setcounter{angle}{0}
%
\begin{document}
\newcommand*{\DNASequence}[2][Mark]{%
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12091/tikz-foreach-loop-with-macro-defined-list
\def\Sequence{#2}
\foreach [count=\xi] \Label/\Color in \Sequence {%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\XShift}{\NodeSize*\xi}%
    \IfStrEq{\Color}{}{\def\Color{white}}{}
    \edef\NodeName{#1-\arabic{ColumnCounter}}
    \node [DNA Style, fill=\Color, xshift=\XShift] (\NodeName) {\Label};
    \stepcounter{ColumnCounter}
} 
}%


\begin{frame}{bla}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\DNASequence{AAAA/cyan,, Big/orange,,,Small/blue,,G/red!25,,C/yellow};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: I need  `\DNASequence` function which draws arbitrary text in the nodes.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is adapted from my earlier answer at [Display issues drawing DNA sequences with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81983/display-issues-drawing-dna-sequences-with-tikz/82230#82230):

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xstring,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newlength{\NodeSize}

\tikzset{DNA Style/.style={minimum size=0.5cm, draw=gray, line width=1pt, inner sep = 2pt}}{}


\newcounter{ColumnCounter}% Prefix for node labels


\newlength{\CurrentXPos}
\newcommand*{\PreviousNode}{}%
\newcommand*{\DNASequence}[2][Mark]{%
    % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12091/tikz-foreach-loop-with-macro-defined-list
    \def\Sequence{#2}%
    \def\PreviousNode{}%
    \foreach [count=\xi] \Label/\Color in \Sequence {%
        \IfStrEq{\Color}{}{\def\Color{white}}{}
        \edef\NodeName{#1-\arabic{ColumnCounter}}
        \IfStrEq{\PreviousNode}{}{%
            \node [DNA Style, fill=\Color, anchor=west] (\NodeName) {\Label};
            \xdef\PreviousNode{\NodeName}%
        }{
            \node [DNA Style, fill=\Color, anchor=west, xshift=-\pgflinewidth] at (\PreviousNode.east)(\NodeName) {\Label};
            \xdef\PreviousNode{\NodeName}%
        }
        \stepcounter{ColumnCounter}
    } 
}%



\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
    \DNASequence{ABCC/magenta!20,,, XYZ/violet!30,,ABC/green, G/blue!20,, G/cyan!30,, C/olive};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[yshift=-1cm]
    \DNASequence{ABCDEFGHS/brown!20,, XYS/cyan!30,,, G/blue!20,, G/orange!30,, C/blue!30, X/red!20, Y/yellow!75};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: NOOO, If you put many letters instead of one letter then everything shifts.

Comment: @msh: Have adapted it for your requirements...