# Draw a vertical DNA sequence on LaTeX and highlight points with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I was googling around of ways to generate a plot like this, but I don't know how to plot this vertically. Since I started with LaTeX 30 minutes ago.

This is a reference to the [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112730/tikz-modify-code-for-drawing-dna-sequence) where I got the initial idea for this:

I'm attaching a picture of what I'm trying to accomplish

[image: commercial photography locations]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  Please help us helping you by giving a MWE with the code, you already tried yourself.

Comment: Have a look at the tiki package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112732/110998) modified such that the strands go top down instead of left right.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xstring,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}

\newlength{\NodeSize}

\tikzset{DNA Style/.style={minimum size=0.5cm, draw=gray, line width=1pt, inner sep = 2pt}}{}


\newcounter{ColumnCounter}% Prefix for node labels


\newlength{\CurrentXPos}
\newcommand*{\PreviousNode}{}%
\newcommand*{\DNASequence}[2][Mark]{%
    % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12091/tikz-foreach-loop-with-macro-defined-list
    \def\Sequence{#2}%
    \def\PreviousNode{}%
    \foreach [count=\xi] \Label/\Color in \Sequence {%
        \IfStrEq{\Color}{}{\def\Color{white}}{}
        \edef\NodeName{#1-\arabic{ColumnCounter}}
        \IfStrEq{\PreviousNode}{}{%
            \node [DNA Style, fill=\Color, anchor=south west] (\NodeName) {\Label};
            \xdef\PreviousNode{\NodeName}%
        }{
            \node [DNA Style, fill=\Color, anchor=north west, yshift=\pgflinewidth] at (\PreviousNode.south west)(\NodeName) {\Label};
            \xdef\PreviousNode{\NodeName}%
        }
        \stepcounter{ColumnCounter}
    } 
}%

\begin{document}
\tikzset{note/.style={circle,draw,align=left}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
    \DNASequence[cell]{ABCC/magenta!20,,,XYZ/violet!30,,ABC/green, G/blue!20,, G/cyan!30,,C/olive};
    \node[note] (note1) at ($(cell-3)+(2,0)$) {Observe\\this};
    \node[note] (note2) [below=of note1] {And this,\\too!};
    \draw[->] (note1) -- (cell-3);
    \draw[->] (note2) -- (cell-7);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```