# How to create a DNA like figure

Tags: packages

I would like to create a sequence like the one in slide 5 of this [Stanford set of slides on edit distance](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs124/lec/med.pdf).

I would like something like this:
[image]

I don't know what package I can use to do this hence, I haven't done anything yet. Do you know what package can be used for this?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Could you add the image of the sequence  to your question and what have you done so far?

Comment: Possibly related (no duplicate, though): https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16572/4918

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you thought of the image on the slide Minimum Edit Distance, here is a code for that:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \foreach \x/\y/\z in {0/I/*, 1/N/E,2/T/X,3/E/E, 4/*/C, 5/N/U,6/T/T,7/I/I,8/O/O,9/N/N}
        {
            \pgfmathsetmacro\coord{\x * 0.3}
            \node (x\x) at (\coord,0) {\y};
            \node (y\x) at (\coord,-1) {\z};
            \draw (x\x) -- (y\x);
        }
\foreach \x/\y in {0/d,1/s,2/s,4/i,5/s}
{
        \pgfmathsetmacro\coord{\x * 0.3};
        \node[anchor=base] at (\coord,-1.5) {\texttt{\y}};
}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Edit: I have to mention @AndréC's answer for [Vertically misaligned node in tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/454121/vertically-misaligned-node-in-tikz/454123#454123) which partly helped me creating this figure.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a realization with `xparse`. It should be clear what's the role of the first optional argument and of the second. The character `!` produces nothing and helps for the alignment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse,array,booktabs}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\sed}{O{\normalsize}mmo}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}
  \ttfamily #1
  \begin{tabular}{ @{} *{ \tl_count:n { #2 } } { w{c}{0.6em}@{} } l @{} }
  \tl_map_function:nN { #2 } \ryuza_cell:n \\ \addlinespace
  \tl_map_function:nN { #2 } \ryuza_empty:n \\ \addlinespace
  \tl_map_function:nN { #3 } \ryuza_cell:n
  \IfValueT { #4 }
   { \\ \addlinespace \tl_map_function:nN { #4 } \ryuza_cell:n }
  \end{tabular}
  \group_end:
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \ryuza_cell:n
 {
  \str_if_eq:nnTF { #1 } { ! } { } { #1 } &
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \ryuza_empty:n
 {
  $\Big|$ &
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\sed
  {INTE*NTION}
  {*EXECUTION}
\sed[\Large]
  {INTE*NTION}
  {*EXECUTION}
  [dss!is!!!!]

\end{document}
```

[image]